# Bibliography entry containing <>

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, doi

Using BibTeX, I'm trying to add a DOI `10.1002/(SICI)1097-0118(199902)30:2<71::AID-JGT1>3.0.CO;2-G` to my bibliography.  However, the presence of the `<` and `>` characters causes problems.

Is there a good way to add such a DOI?

I'm using a bibliography style which has been processed with [urlbst](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/urlbst/) to support DOI and URL fields.  My current workaround is to drop the DOI field.  Instead I add a field

> `url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0118(199902)30:2<71::AID-JGT1>3.0.CO;2-G},`

which seems to work, but it would be preferable to use the DOI directly.

Comment: The DOI spec is *broken*, for allowing all "the legal graphic characters of Unicode", and Wiley is **insane** for actually using them (or trying, and failing to do so). Your exmaple is bad with the `<>`, but try using this one with a `#` (fragment ident): `10.1002/(SICI)1521-3978(200005)48:5/7<531::AID-PROP531>3.0.CO;2-#`. Even after you convince tex to deal with it, good luck getting it to work: http://www.doi.org/syntax.html says to encode `#` as `%23` for URLs, which gets past `http://dx.doi.org/` but still fails. I'm pretty sure Wiley has come up with a DOI that is impossible to resolve!

Comment: They usually work from something like JabRef via Firefox for me, but I agree that they are a pain in the neck!

Comment: maybe this helps: http://shortdoi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0118%28199902%2930:2%3C71::AID-JGT1%3E3.0.CO;2-G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual solution to OP's problem is to encode the < and > signs as their hexadecimal representation:

the "smaller than sign" becomes %3C

the "larger than sign" becomes %3E

If you do this together (!) with using the doi package the links in the bibliography will actually work. More information including other nasty characters can be found here

http://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/2_Numbering.html#2.2

and here

http://www.doi.org/syntax.html

Failing to do this will result in broken links no matter what.

Answer (score 8):

There is the [`doi`](http://www.tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/doi/) package that gives you the command `\doi{...}` that will probably do exactly what you want.

Comment: incidentally, this is the second hit when you google "LaTeX DOI"...

Comment: How would you mix that with BibTeX?

Comment: `doi ={\doi{...}}`, I presume...

Answer (score 4):

I was having similar problems with underscores in doi's, and found that using [BibLaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) solved the problem.

Comment: I'd prefer to stick to BibTeX for now -- I have an otherwise perfectly functional style file and don't have time to switch right now.