# How to get DOI links in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, natbib, doi

I would like to add to all my bibliography items a DOI (Digital Object Identifier) link or a link to a download location.

How can I do this with the `natbib` / BibTeX / `hyperref`  combination? Currently I am using the `plainnat` style, but I'm willing to change that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3039/bibliography-entry-containing (which comes up as the second hit when you search this site for DOI)

Comment: @Seamus No, that question is about solving a problem with doi's, while I could not figure out how to it completely. Related: yes, dupliate: no.

Comment: 1) I still don't think the questions are different. 2) Your first move should be to try and google/search tex SE for an answer, and you would have found one

Comment: @Seamus Check for example http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=doi+links+bibliography+natbib It is not clear for me what the solution is. And no, on this website there was no clear answer for my question.

Comment: I'd agree with Peter: the question is not a duplicate (the previous one is about a very specific issue), although the relation between the two is clear.

Comment: Not 100 % relevant to your question but also check this link which uses biblatex. The result is very beautiful:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49564/how-do-i-turn-titles-into-hyperlinks-in-verbose-mode-using-biblatex-and-hyperref

Comment: I would like to have the Journal name linked with the doi, like it's done in some jounal papers. How do you realize that?

Comment: @laclaro: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Include your DOIs in the BibTeX database under the `doi` field and include the URLs under the `url` field; for example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{foo2010,
  author = "Foo Bar",
  journal = "J.P.B.",
  year = 2010,
  title = "Where the wild things are.",
  doi = {10.1.1/jpb001},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1.1/jpb001}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\begin{document}
test \citet{foo2010}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

If you wish to hyperlink the DOI, I believe that loading the [`doi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doi) package will perform this automatically.

Comment: Worked great for me, I just had to download doi.sty from: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/doi

Comment: @Will Robertson the font of the doi numbers differs from the rest of the text. Can I fix its font (or, if necessary, the size) to be coherent with the references?

Comment: The font of the doi numbers differs from the rest of the text. Can I change the font style, size, color, etc. of the doi only?

Comment: I seem to have a conflict between the `DOI` package and the `verse` and `hyperref` packages. Loading the `DOI` package after each one does not seem to address the conflict. Anyone else have a similar issue?

Comment: \usepackage{doi} solved it for me in Overleaf with natbib, abbrevnat using pdfLatex compiler. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

A minimal change would be to use the `plainurl` style instead of `plainnat`.

You could also continue to use `plainnat` and give a suitable definition of `\doi` (to override the non-hyperlinked version \provided by plainnat), eg:

```
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: #1}}
```

In both cases, just use a `doi` field in your .bib file.

Comment: What does plainurl add? Oh, I see, hyperlinks in the DOI. Sorry, was confused for a minute.

Comment: I changed the bibtex style from plainnat to plainurl, but now each reference contains both the DOI and a URL to the same DOI, e.g: "URL: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0925-7721(93)90007-s, doi:10.1016/0925-7721(93)90007-s.".  This is redundant. Is there a way to tell BibTeX to show only the DOI, without the URL?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: yes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5660/redundancy-in-bib-file-conditionally-suppress-url-if-same-as-doi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please note that the preferred DOI resolver is [`https://doi.org/`](https://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/3_Resolution.html#3.8), without the `dx` subdomain.

Answer (score 39):

I came across this thread recently while solving a variant of Peter's question.

Instead of adding a hyperlink DOI to each of the bibliography items, you may want not to write the DOI explicitly but to make another field of the bibliographic item clickable with an hyperlink to the download location. In some journals, the hyperlink is associated to the group "Journal Name, volume, page number" for instance.
You may find some existing bibliography style files doing that, but sometimes you need to add this feature to a personal bibliography style. In this case, none of the above solutions work. The hack I came up with is to define the following function in the `.bst` file:

```
FUNCTION {doilink}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ doi empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
if$
}
```

Here is an example of how to call the function:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  boldface
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    {  ", " * pages first.page.number * }
      if$
    }
  if$
  doilink
}
```

In this case the volume and pages will be hyperlinks. In general the hyperlink will be associated to the item on the top of the stack when the function `doilink` is called. You also need to make sure that the `doi` is declared as a possible field for bibliographic entries. As a minimal example:

```
ENTRY
{ author
  doi
  journal
  key
  pages
  title
  volume
  year
}
```

This may not be the most robust solution but it solved my problem. I thought it might be useful to some people here.

EDIT

Following @laclaro 's [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76116/16873), I add an example of a `.tex` file calling the modified `.bst` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.,0.,0.4}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0.,0.}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkred,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Brune1996,
    Author = {Brune, M  and Hagley, E and Dreyer, J and Maître, X and  Maali, A and Wunderlich, C and Raimond,J.M. and Haroche,S },
    Title = {Observing the Progressive Decoherence of the “Meter” in a Quantum Measurement},
    Year = {1996},
    Journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
    volume = {77},
    pages = {4887},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.4887}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\cite{Brune1996}

\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Here, clicking on the volume or page number opens the doi link. To adapt this so that the hyperlink is on the journal, you would need to modify the function `FUNCTION {format.journal}` in the `.bst` style file rather than the `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}` as was done here.

Comment: with biblatex and the eprint field, you can also add arxiv or oai links as offered by the Hal open archive http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/oai-field-in-bibtex-biblatex

Comment: How would one extend this code to use the `url` field if the `doi` field is not present? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565638/45154

Answer (score 30):

Will Robertson showed how to do it with `natbib` and `hyperref` (as requested by the original poster). The most important point is of course to have a doi field in your bib file.
Another solution would be to use `biblatex` instead of `natbib`. My experience is that `biblatex`is at the same time very flexible and very stable, especially when some fileds (e.g name or doi) contain strange/special characters. Here is a MWE that should compile fine as it is:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    natbib=true,
    sortlocale=en_US,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{kastenholz}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo~\citet{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a further question, is it possible to have the `doi` field point to the address specified by `url`? Because prepending *http://dx.doi.org/* would point you to an address which would likely redirect you again, then it makes sense for us to put the actual address in `url` and let `doi` link directly to its value.

Comment: The URL might change, the DOI is a permanent identifier. So, please always use the DOI where possible. The redirect is not a problem, it is part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense!

Comment: @matth Note that both [crossref](https://www.crossref.org/display-guidelines/#:~:text=Crossref%20DOIs%20should%3A,name%20part%20of%20DOI%20links) and [datacite](https://support.datacite.org/docs/datacite-doi-display-guidelines) explicitly recommend displaying DOIs using complete URLs (see data cite link for reasons). I am also interested in learning how to get biblatex to do this (i.e. add the `https://doi.org/` prefix when displaying the doi field).

Comment: @leopold.talirz See [this issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/885). You can just add `\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}`.

Answer (score 26):

@Lev: that worked, although DOIs can contain special latex characters like underscores, such as:

https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-08755-9_9

So I modified your hack to:

```
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/\detokenize{#1}}{doi: \detokenize{#1}}}
```

Comment: Some of the strangest DOIs I have in my .bib file are: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/1521-4001(200209)82:9<579::AID-ZAMM579>3.0.CO;2-V and http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/1521-4125(200007)23:7<581::AID-CEAT581>3.0.CO;2-P

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3039/627 for more discussion of weird characters in doi strings.

Comment: This prevents doi's from having line breaks. Helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50023/41276

Answer (score 11):

My reference section requires to output doi's also in the bibliography. Inspired from Corentin's solution, I come up with the following hack in the .bst file:

I add a doi field in the ENTRY section, if it does not contain:

```
ENTRY
{ 
    address
    ...
    year
    doi
}
```

Next, I define a function output.doi

```
FUNCTION {output.doi}
{ 
    doi empty$
        { skip$ }
        { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{doi:" * doi * "}" * output }
    if$
}
```

Then, in the entries that I want to report doi field, I call this function, after a new block. In my case, it is required at the end, before the notes:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ 
    ...
    new.block
    output.doi
    new.block
    note output
    fin.entry
}
```

I added the doi field to article, inproceedings and incollection types.

For a bib entry with doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-20946-8\_2}, this solution displays a doi:10.1007/978-3-642-20946-8_2 reference at the bibliography, and when clicked it links to http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-20946-8_2 address.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding my piece, I have myself revised the `.bst` style I wanted (apalike) to include ISBN, ISSN, DOI, and URL. I did not find any "apalikeurl" version so far, so I did it myself. It builds links for DOIs and ISBNs, and for ISBNs it is even capable of managing several IDs in the same field (i.e. one link for each).

https://github.com/matthieu-vergne/LaTeX/blob/master/apalike-refs.bst

Now I wonder if there is a way to use options for the style to say which IDs to accept for the display. I made all that just yesterday and did not have the time to investigate further. Comments and fixes are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in unsrt style, i used the code [here](https://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/adding-the-doi-to-the-unsrt-bibliography-style-in-latex/) and modified a line with the help from a reply [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127819/78250) and it worked perfectly as I wanted.

The modified part of the code:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
new.block
format.title "title" output.check
new.block
crossref missing$
{ journal emphasize "journal" output.check
    format.vol.num.pages output
    format.date "year" output.check
}
{ format.article.crossref output.nonnull
    format.pages output
}
if$
format.doi output
new.block
output.doi
note output
fin.entry
}
```

Save the code to your directory as "unsrtDOI.bst" and at the end of your latex file:

```
\bibliography{b.bib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtDOI}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to include them in the `notes` field of your `.bib`. Some bibliography management tools do that when exporting, like the PMID to bib converter https://www.bioinformatics.org/texmed/

It automatically provides a `notes` field with the appropriate content:

```
\href{<Link to PUBMED>}{<PMID #>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the url as an additional note in the following way

@article{Foi,

```
Author = {ABC},

 ...
 ....

 note={\url{https://doi.org/10.1006/s00454-016-00156-0}},
```

Answer (score -1):

For IEEE style numerical citation, import package `natlib` with option numbers:

`\usepackage[numbers]{natlib}`

Source: [More Options,page 5](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf)