# OAI field in biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, doi

Similarly to DOI, will an OAI ([Open Archives Initiative](http://www.openarchives.org/)) field be soon added to bibtex/biblatex styles?

Comment: I've never seen OAI identifiers used in a reflist, and the [OAI identifier standard](http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/guidelines-oai-identifier.htm) says "oai-identifiers are not designed for human use, they are designed to be used only with the OAI-PMH" - have you got a sample of their use in a reflist?

Comment: ok, here is a document with such a reference `http://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00451733/fr/` See the reference page [last page] and reference Sidoroff. There is an oai reference with an hyperlink to the appropriate webpage. I think we should see more of this kind of link as long as pdf is the norm (which won't last soomuch longer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of experts, here is one solution that satisfies oai requirements. The oai references require a repository and a number such as, for instance oai:hal.example.com:hal-0000001 that can be used to reconstruct the actual internet address of the document of interest, here : http://hal.example.com/hal-000001/

The eprint and eprinttype fields together with the following definition shall be used:

```
\def\oaitourl#1:#2{#1/#2}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:oai}%
{oai:\href{http://\oaitourl#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{EX}
\end{document}
```

together with, in the .bib file :

```
@TechReport{EX,
author =      {Name, First name},
title =       {Report},
institution = {INH},
year =        {2010},
eprint =      {hal.example.com:hal-000000001},
eprinttype =  {oai}}
```

The thing is that it would be even better with an oai field directly in the .bib file.

**edit:** This approach requires the use of the `biblatex` package together with the `biber` engine.

Comment: I get this error with the command **DeclareFieldFormat** https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-30%20at%2013.38.27.png Do you know why?

Comment: @Masi you have to use `biblatex` and the associated `biber` engine in this approach: `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=nyt,       sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,backref=true]{biblatex}`. From your file, you seem to be using `natbib` with `bibtex` I would say. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Masi please retry with `biblatex` and `biber` and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any reference to OAI in the [Feature Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=244752&atid=1126006) of the biblatex page at sourceforge. You should consider to create a feature request.

Comment: after reading biblatex guide, I feel that considering a request on the oai field or offering a patch may be appropriate. Other people than just myself may be soon interested in this field.

Comment: @pluton: did you submit a feature request? I can't find any tickets with keyword `oai`.

Comment: @anderstood nope because I am quite happy with the provided solution. This could be requested as a feature, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

biblatex has resources for custom field types. (p. 26 of `texdoc biblatex` ) It would mean modifying the bibliography style (since none of the standard types make use of, say `verba` ). So it is already possible to make use of oai fields, with a little work...

Comment: yes, coming back to lockstep's suggestion and my original post, it may be a the bst-like style level that the oai field could be added. I'll try to investigate.