# In biblatex-chicago, what is the appropriate field/entry type for an online database?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I use JSTOR and Google books/scholar a lot for my essays, and while they provide bibtex-style citations, chicago style dictates that the database name be in the citation. I've read through the biblatex-chicago pdf and couldn't find anything specifically pertaining to these types of citations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please share an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) with us? It would be important to know if you use the notes or authordate style of `biblatex-chicago`. Furthermore it would be nice to know how you give the relevant data in the `.bib` file. Finally, it would be great of you could give us an idea of how you would ideally like to see the information shown in the end (i.e. create a mock-up).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `eprint`. Put the ID of the entry into the `eprint` field and then give the kind of database in the `eprinttype`. For example

```
@article{nagaev1979,
  author     = {S. V. Nagaev},
  journal    = {Annals of Probability},
  number     = {5},
  pages      = {745-789},
  title      = {Large Deviations of Sums of Independent Random Variables},
  volume     = {7},
  date       = {1979},
  eprint     = {2243301},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
}

@book{wilde,
  author       = {Wilde, Oscar},
  title        = {The Importance of Being Earnest: A Trivial Comedy for Serious
                  People},
  year         = 1899,
  series       = {English and {American} drama of the Nineteenth Century},
  publisher    = {Leonard Smithers {and} Company},
  eprint       = {4HIWAAAAYAAJ},
  eprinttype   = {googlebooks},
}
```

Out of the box `biblatex` supports JSTOR (`eprinttype = {jstor}`), arxiv (`eprinttype = {arxiv}`), HDLs (`eprinttype = {hdl}`), PubMed (`eprinttype = {pubmed}`), Google Books (`eprinttype = {googlebooks}`). Have a look at [Biblatex and Pubmed/Pubmed Central IDs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864) for help on adding new eprint types.

DOIs are supported in a dedicated `doi` field.

Since `biblatex-chicago` fully supports `biblatex`'s eprint features, you can use this with `biblatex-chicago` as well.