# Biber and PubMed/PubMedCentral IDs with Bibdesk default field names

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibdesk

I would like to modify the MWE presented in

[Biblatex and Pubmed/Pubmed Central IDs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155532/biblatex-and-pubmed-pubmed-central-ids/471972#471972)

The working example presented there works perfectly, but now I'd like to modify it to work with a BibDesk-generated file where `Pmc` is used for the PubMedCentral ID field, and `Pmid` is used for the PubMed ID field.  So I modified the MWE by replacing `pmcid` with `Pmc` and `pmid` with `Pmid`, but it does not work in that now neither the PMCID nor the PMID parts appear in the typeset PDF (see code below) - any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ContEp,
  author        = {Mark G. Frei and Hitten P. Zaveri and Susan Arthurs and Gregory K. Bergey and Christophe Jouny and Klaus Lehnertz and Jean Gotman and Ivan Osorio and Theoden I. Netoff and Walter J. Freeman and John Jefferys and Gregory Worrell and Michel Le Van Quyen and Steven J. Schiff and Florian Mormannn},
  title         = {Controversies in epilepsy},
  subtitle      = {Debates held during the Fourth International Workshop on Seizure Prediction},
  journaltitle  = {Epilepsy \& Behavior},
  volume        = {19},
  number        = {1},
  pages         = {4-16},
  date          = {2010-09},
  doi           = {10.1016/j.yebeh.2010.06.009},
  Pmc         = {PMC2943379},
  Pmid          = {20708976},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{Pmid}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{Pmid}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{Pmc}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{Pmc}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:Pmc}{%
  PMCID\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:PMC}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:PMCID}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:pmc}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{Pmc}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{Pmid}{eprint:pubmed}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{Pmc}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{Pmid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{ContEp}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, is there a way to instruct BibDesk to use `pmcid` and `pmid` field labels when importing from PubMed?

Answer (score 3):

While the BibTeX/`.bib`-file side of things is not case sensitive, the LaTeX side of things is (because TeX is case sensitive).

In practice that means that in your `.bib` file you can write `Pmid`, `pmid`, `PMID` or `pMiD` and they all mean the same thing, but in your `.tex` file and in `biblatex` configurations those four strings are not the same. The `biblatex` side of things assumes that all field names (and also entry types) are in lowercase (if in doubt, assuming that internal `biblatex` names use lowercase only is a good guess).

So you must write `\printfield{pmc}%` and also `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{pmid}`, etc. etc.

The following example works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ContEp,
  author        = {Mark G. Frei and Hitten P. Zaveri and Susan Arthurs and Gregory K. Bergey and Christophe Jouny and Klaus Lehnertz and Jean Gotman and Ivan Osorio and Theoden I. Netoff and Walter J. Freeman and John Jefferys and Gregory Worrell and Michel Le Van Quyen and Steven J. Schiff and Florian Mormannn},
  title         = {Controversies in epilepsy},
  subtitle      = {Debates held during the Fourth International Workshop on Seizure Prediction},
  journaltitle  = {Epilepsy \& Behavior},
  volume        = {19},
  number        = {1},
  pages         = {4-16},
  date          = {2010-09},
  doi           = {10.1016/j.yebeh.2010.06.009},
  Pmc           = {PMC2943379},
  Pmid          = {20708976},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{pmid}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{pmid}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{pmc}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{pmc}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:Pmc}{%
  PMCID\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:PMC}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:PMCID}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:pmc}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{pmc}{eprint:Pmc}
\DeclareFieldAlias{pmid}{eprint:pubmed}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pmc}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pmid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{ContEp}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Frei, Mark G. et al. (Sept. 2010). “Controversies in epilepsy. Debates held during the Fourth International Workshop on Seizure Prediction”. In: Epilepsy & Behavior 19.1, pp. 4–16. doi: 10.1016/j.yebeh.2010.06.009. PMCID: PMC2943379. PMID: 20708976.]

Note that the capitalisation of the `eprint:...` field formats is different from the capitalisation of proper fields. That is because the `eprint` field formats rely not only on the internal name of the field (`eprint`), but also on the content of the `eprinttype` field (which is case sensitive, hence `eprint:PMC` and `eprint:pmc` are different).

In your setup most `eprint` formats are not needed, so

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pmc}{%
  PMCID\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldAlias{pmid}{eprint:pubmed}
```

should be enough and might be clearer as to what is going on.