# How to use eprinttype with medrxiv?

Tags: bibtex, citing

When I publish a preprint on arXiv, I use `eprint` and `eprinttype` fields in my bibtex citations. This nicely converts the identifier into a link and the reference is not cluttered with the whole URL of the article. When the paper gets properly published, I just add the `doi` field and the person who sees such citation finds the original published version, but also can access the preprint which is not behind a paywall.

**How can I do this for medrXiv preprint?** `eprinttype = {medrxiv}` does not work (It just thinks it is an ArXiv preprint). The [biblatex package manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) does not say anything about medrxiv. I know that medrxiv has a DOI which I can use, but when the paper gets published in a journal it will have another DOI. And two `doi` fields do not make sense in one citation.

To clarify, I am looking for a general solution, which would work out of the box (no custom definitions), because I want to create a bib code which I would put on my web/Git/ORCID for the people to see how they can cite that particular work.

Comment: If and how this is possible will strongly depend on the bibliography package (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and `biblatex` style you use. Ideally you would share your bibliography setup in a short example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). In `biblatex` it is fairly easy to add a new eprint type (see the first part of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864: you basically only need to provide a suitable definition in `\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:<new eprint type>}{<code where #1 is the eprint identifier>}`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for pointing out the possibility of adding a new eprint type. But I was hoping for some more general solution which would work for people out of the box. I should have specified this in the question (I edited the question). I want to create a bib code for my publication which I can display e.g. on my web/Git/ORCID for the people to see how they can cite the work. So defining anything custom is out of the question.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid your only option that is going to be understood by a variety of packages (especially without further customisations) is to use a generic field like `note`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Would you suggest making a feature request somewhere? If yes, where? Biblatex community maybe? This is a standard thing, publishing a preprint and then having it published in a journal. I believe it is important to make your preprint link easily accessible because it gives your readers an easy access to your work which is otherwise behind a paywall. Also, have you considered putting those two options into an answer so I can mark it solved?

Comment: Many BibTeX styles are not really developed any more (of course some still are), but you can put in a feature request for `biblatex` at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no style that supports [medRxiv](https://www.medrxiv.org/), [bioRxiv](https://www.biorxiv.org/) or [ChemRxiv](https://chemrxiv.org/) out of the box.

Many older (and still used) BibTeX styles don't even know a `url` field. But even with newer styles there is fragmentation in how exactly they implement the `eprint` field, which usually points to the arXiv. With classical BibTeX your best bet for any of this is usually the `note` field.

`biblatex` makes it very easy to add new eprint types (see for example [Biblatex and Pubmed/Pubmed Central IDs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864)), but the three ...Rxivs are not supported from the get go.

It appears to me that medRxiv, bioRXiv and ChemRxiv basically assign DOIs (if they have internal identifiers they are certainly not as catchy as the arXiv IDs), so maybe you can use the `doi` field (which is not supported by all styles, but quite prevalent in more modern styles; of course that is not an option if there is also a DOI of the published article).

---

Bottom line: The only thing that works reliably across styles is

```
note = {medRxiv 2020.05.14.20101758},
```