# Add a new field to bibliography items with biblatex+biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using biblatex and biber with the following definitions:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  backref=true,
  % firstinits=true,
  style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage  = {cited on p.},
  backrefpages = {cited on pp.}
}
```

I have a bibliography item defined like this:

```
@book{yellow-hl-lhc,
  author = "Apollinari, G and Béjar Alonso, I and Brüning, O and Lamont, M and
    Rossi, L",
  title  = "{High-Luminosity Large Hadron Collider (HL-LHC):
    Preliminary Design Report}",
  publisher = "CERN",
  address   = "Geneva",
  series    = "CERN Yellow Reports: Monographs",
  year      = "2015",
  url       = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/2116337",
  doi       = "10.5170/CERN-2015-005"
}
```

which comes out like this:

[image]

Is it possible to define a new field called `cds` that should work like `doi`, so in the `.bib` file I could write `cds = "2116337"` and it would add "CDS: 2116337" to the item in the bibliography with the number linked to the URL?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864 help?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll write up what I did as an answer when I have time.

Comment: Is what you did so different from the answer there that it warrants a new answer of its own or would you say it would also be OK to close this question here as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, here is the listing of what I did, based on the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155536/35990), which was suggested in the comments.

Inside `biblatex-dm.cfg`, which can be put in the same directory as the main `.tex` file,

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{cds}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{cds}
```

In the main `.tex`, after `\usepackage{biblatex}`, before the `\begin{document}`,

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{cds}{%
  \textsc{cds}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://cds.cern.ch/record/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{cds}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}
```