# Display TEL/HAL eprints with the same design as ArXiv preprints with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

using biblatex, I want to hide the full URL of some phd references on TEL (thèse en ligne) and HAL (Hyper articles en ligne) and just display the actual reference number that will link to the proper URL when clicked. Exactly how ArXiv references are displayed here.

Here is a MWE, notice how the two different entries are displayed. I want the PhD entry to be displayed same as the ArXiv one, without displaying the entire URL but rather the ID saying something like "TEL: " with the  being clickable and linking directly to the actual URL.

```
\documentclass[french, 11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
The arXiv eprint: \cite{2018arXiv180609824G}\\
Some PhD on HAL/TEL: \cite{olry:tel-00005985}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliographie}]
\end{document}
```

With biblio.bib as such, directly downloaded from arxiv and tel.

```
@phdthesis{olry:tel-00005985,
  TITLE = {{Etude d'une cavite acc{\'e}l{\'e}ratrice supraconductrice Spoke pour les acc{\'e}l{\'e}rateurs de protons de forte intensit{\'e}}},
  AUTHOR = {Olry, Guillaume},
  URL = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00005985},
  HAL_LOCAL_REFERENCE = {IPNO-T-04-02},
  SCHOOL = {{Universit{\'e} Paris-Diderot - Paris VII}},
  YEAR = {2004},
  MONTH = Apr,
  KEYWORDS = {cavit{\'e}s spoke ; supraconductivit{\'e} ; acc{\'e}l{\'e}rateur lin{\'e}aire {\`a} protons ; contr{\^o}le dimensionnel},
  TYPE = {Theses},
  PDF = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00005985/file/tel-00005985.pdf},
  HAL_ID = {tel-00005985},
  HAL_VERSION = {v1},
}

@ARTICLE{2018arXiv180609824G,
   author = {{Grassellino}, A. and {Romanenko}, A. and {Bice}, D. and {Melnychuk}, O. and 
    {Crawford}, A.~C. and {Chandrasekaran}, S. and {Sung}, Z. and 
    {Sergatskov}, D.~A. and {Checchin}, M. and {Posen}, S. and {Martinello}, M. and 
    {Wu}, G.},
    title = "{Accelerating fields up to 49 MV/m in TESLA-shape superconducting RF niobium cavities via 75C vacuum bake}",
  journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1806.09824},
 primaryClass = "physics.acc-ph",
 keywords = {Physics - Accelerator Physics},
     year = 2018,
    month = jun,
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018arXiv180609824G},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

By the way, if there is a way to frenchasize biblatex using the French quotation marks «» and not the English ones "". As well as printing the "et al." in italic I would be down to know how as well.
Thank you.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151628/35864 help? To fully frenchify things you can load `babel` with the `french` option and load `csquotes`. If you still want to write in English and just use French quotation marks (not sure if that is wise), you need a few tricks like `\usepackage[style=french]{csquotes}`.

Comment: How can I tell a HAL from a TEL given your `.bib` entries?

Comment: I guess tel have a link format as tel-xxxxxx and hal don't. I am trying to do something with the `DeclareFieldFormat` from biblatex.

Comment: Please verify this. If there is no other indication for HAL vs TEL in the `.bib` data that makes things a bit harder. `\DeclareFieldFormat` won't be enough if you want to use `hal_id` and friends, you will need to declare them in the data model to be able to use them (see my link).

Comment: it seems it actually is, [for example](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00218793v1) with id being jpa-00218793v1 is then an article.
What if i manually change the bib file so that `eprint = {tel-00005985}` and `eprinttype = {tel}`. Is the `\DeclareFieldFormat` enough to declare a new URL for TEL. PS: it don't seem to but i'm working on it.

Comment: As it turns out the HAL resolver works for `tel-` as well: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00005985 So do you really need to link TELs to the special `tel.archives-ouvertes.fr` resolver. If you were to use `eprint` and `eprinttype` that would drastically simplify things. You would not need a data model file for Biber and could do things with only `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Comment: Then it's fine to link it to hal.archives-ouvertes/
I've emailed HAL, it would be weird that they don't propose a data model sheet or something. I haven't found it online.
Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can implement e-print archives like HAL. (1) With a dedicated field (`hal` in the MWE) or (2) with `eprint` and `eprinttype`.

(1) needs a new 'datamodel' (`.dbx`) file to make the new field known to Biber and `biblatex`. (2) Needs no such thing since the `eprint` field exists already. But there is only one `eprint` field, so if you want to give multiple e-print identifiers you will have to resort to a new field at some point.

[BibTeX fields for DOI, MR, Zbl and arxiv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151628/35864) shows the general approach you could take. The MWE below shows both the approach with `eprint` and with a dedicated `hal` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{eprint-hal.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{eprint-hal.dbx}[2018/09/26 HAL/TEL eprints]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{arxiv,hal}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{hal}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{arxivclass}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{arxivclass}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=ynt,
    datamodel=eprint-hal,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{hal}{%
  \mkbibacro{HAL}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:hal}{hal}
\DeclareFieldAlias{eprint:HAL}{eprint:hal}

\renewbibmacro*{eprint}{%
  \printfield{hal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\printfield{eprint}}
    {\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{olry:tel-00005985,
  title       = {Etude d'une cavite accélératrice supraconductrice Spoke pour les accélérateurs de protons de forte intensité},
  author      = {Olry, Guillaume},
  school      = {Universit{\'e} Paris-Diderot -- Paris VII},
  date        = {2004-04},
  hal         = {tel-00005985},
}
@article{sasso:hal-01882235,
  title      = {Performances of Four Real-Time PCR Assays for Diagnosis of Pneumocystis jirovecii Pneumonia},
  author     = {Sasso, Milène and Chastang-Dumas, Elsa and Bastide, Sophie and Alonso, Sandrine and Lechiche, Catherine and Bourgeois, Nathalie and Lachaud, Laurence},
  journal    = {Journal of Clinical Microbiology},
  volume     = {54},
  number     = {3},
  pages      = {625 - 630},
  date       = {2016-02},
  eprint     = {hal-01882235},
  eprinttype = {hal},
}
@phdthesis{waldvogel:tel-01881957,
  title      = {Development of an efficient catalyst for the process chain Power-to-Methane and kinetic study},
  author     = {Waldvogel, Audrey},
  school     = {Université de Strasbourg},
  date       = {2017-12},
  eprint     = {tel-01881957},
  eprinttype = {HAL},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
The arXiv eprint: \cite{wassenberg}

Some PhD on HAL/TEL: \cite{olry:tel-00005985,sasso:hal-01882235,waldvogel:tel-01881957}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliographie}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Guillaume Olry. « Etude d’une cavite accélératrice supraconductrice Spoke pour les accélérateurs de protons de forte intensité ». Thèse de doct. Université Paris-Diderot – Paris VII, avr. 2004. hal : tel-00005985.//Jan Wassenberg et Peter Sanders. Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining. Version 1. 17 août 2010. arXiv : 1008.2849v1 [cs.DS].//Milène Sasso et al. « Performances of Four Real-Time PCR Assays for Diagnosis of Pneumocystis jirovecii Pneumonia ». In : Journal of Clinical Microbiology 54.3 (fév. 2016), p. 625-630. hal : hal-01882235.//Audrey Waldvogel. « Development of an efficient catalyst for the process chain Power-to-Methane and kinetic study ». Thèse de doct. Université de Strasbourg, déc. 2017. hal : tel-01881957.]

Comment: Awesome thank you. I've played a bit with this definition in order to use the field hal_id