# Biblatex: Add a second URL where content is archived

Tags: biblatex

Is there a possiblity to add a second URL to @online entries?

I would like to display 1. the original URL and 2. an entry in an archiving service (archive.org or webcitation.org) in case the original Site goes down

Related, i also would like to add the name of the Website (e.g. name of the newspaper, Media outlet) similar to Booktitle from @incollection

Comment: Currently you can only have one URL in the `url` field. But with a datamodel file it should be possible to add another `archivalurl` field. You could also make those archival URLs more `eprint`-like (cf. JSTOR). In fact it is quite easy to extend the current `eprint` scheme even without a datamodel file.

Comment: See also [BibTeX fields for DOI, MR, Zbl and arxiv?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151628/35864), [Biblatex and Pubmed/Pubmed Central IDs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864), [OAI field in biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4972/35864)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a new `archiveurl` field with accompanying `archivedate`.

This is done via a  `.dbx` file, we can also add internationalisation. You can read more about this in [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) and [Add field “tome” to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864). The `.dbx` needs to placed somewhere TeX can find it and its name must be given to `biblatex` in the `datamodel` option at loading time. In the MWE the file is created automatically using `filecontents`.

The `.dbx` contains

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=uri]{archiveurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{archiveurl}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  archivedate,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{archivedate}
```

and thus defines two new fields: `archiveurl` and `archivedate`. The former is a URI-type field (a URL) while the latter is a date field.

Then we define the needed strings,  internationalisation can also be done in an `.lbx` file.

```
\NewBibliographyString{archivedat,archivedon}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  archivedat = {archived at},
  archivedon = {on},
}
```

We can define the formats and new macros

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{archiveurl}{\bibstring{archivedat}\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{archivedate}{\bibstring{archivedon}\space#1}

\newbibmacro*{archiveurl}{\printfield{archiveurl}}
\newbibmacro*{archivedate}{\printarchivedate}
```

Finally, we modify the URL macro to also print the archive URL.

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{archiveurl}%
  \iffieldundef{archiveyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{archivedate}}}
```

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}{archiving.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=uri]{archiveurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{archiveurl}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  archivedate,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{archivedate}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle, datamodel=archiving]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{panic,
  author      = {Plunkett, John},
  title       = {Sorrell accuses Murdoch of panic buying},
  journal     = {The Guardian},
  date        = {2005-10-27},
  url         = {http://media.guardian.co.uk/site/story/0,14173,1601858,00.html},
  archiveurl  = {http://www.webcitation.org/5Kt3PxfFl},
  archivedate = {2006-12-04},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewBibliographyString{archivedat,archivedon}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  archivedat = {archived at},
  archivedon = {on},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{archiveurl}{\bibstring{archivedat}\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{archivedate}{\bibstring{archivedon}\space#1}

\newbibmacro*{archiveurl}{\printfield{archiveurl}}
\newbibmacro*{archivedate}{\printarchivedate}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{archiveurl}%
  \iffieldundef{archiveyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{archivedate}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{panic}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```