# Redundancy in bib file: conditionally suppress url if same as doi?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, conditionals, urls, doi

[Mathscinet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet) gives bibtex entries with both a `doi` and a `url` field included. Typically they look something like

```
@article {some-article,
   […] 
   DOI = {10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
   URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
}
```

I'm using `amsalpha.bst`, modified with `urlbst` to process both these fields.  Of course, this means that they both appear, completely redundantly, in my bibliography!

My question is: what's the principled way to deal with this?  Here are the options I've thought of so far:

- Modify the bib file so it checks for this redundancy, and doesn't typeset the url in such cases.   This seems ideal if it's possible; has anyone already done something like this?  If not, is it likely to be doable by someone with a little programming experience but no existing understanding of .bst files?
- Use a bibstyle that typesets one of `url` and `doi` but not both.  Not ideal: other bib entries might have only one but not both, or might have a url different from the doi.
- Comment out (or delete) the `url' field by hand, in the bib file, in these cases.  This is what I'm currently doing.  Seems a little clunky; also, somewhat violates “separation of form from content”: having the fields the same is correct as content, it’s just inappropriate for them then to both be typeset.

Related question: [How to get DOI links in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography)

Comment: I wonder if bibtools has the resources to automagically make your .bib file suitable for one of your listed options... http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools/

Comment: The problem with this is that since the url and doi fields won't be identical, even if they say the same thing, so you can't just check whether they are equal and conditionally print only one of them...

Comment: @Seamus: true, but we know what to look for. I'm at the wrong computer just at the moment, but give me a couple of hours and I think I have a solution :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The modifications made by `urlbst` are quite clear, so the change you want is actually not too hard (by BibTeX standards). If you open up your `.bst` files, you need to search for a function called `output.web.refs`. It needs modifying to read

```
FUNCTION {output.web.refs}
{
  new.block
  output.url
  addeprints eprint empty$ not and
    { format.eprint output.nonnull }
    'skip$
  if$
  adddoiresolver doi empty$ not and
    { 
      url empty$
        { format.doi output.nonnull }
        {
          doiurl doi * url =     
            'skip$
            { format.doi output.nonnull }
          if$  
        } 
      if$  
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  addpubmedresolver pubmed empty$ not and
    { format.pubmed output.nonnull }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

All that has happened here is that I've added a test for an empty URL and a second for the URL being the same as the DOI once the prefix is added.

Comment: Marvellous, works a charm!  The one change I had to make (noting it in case others have the same issue): I had to excise the “addpubmedresolver” block, since my .bst file wasn’t set up to do pubmed data.

Comment: p.s. this has now given me the courage to start playing around with the .bst file myself for the first time, finding that (a) making minor tweaks is not as impossibly arcane as it had previously seemed, but (b) my goodness, it’s a strange language!

Answer (score 22):

The original question is about a standard BibTeX style, but inspired by lockstep I've worked out a [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) solution as a complement to my other answer.  The method here is to add the appropriate prefix to the raw DOI, then test this for equivalence to the URL. The prefix needs to be processed with `\detokenize` as this is how the URL field is formatted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{doi}
        {}
        {%
          \begingroup
          \edef\URLorDOI{%
            \detokenize{http://dx.doi.org/}%
            \thefield{doi}%
          }%
          \iffieldequals{url}{\URLorDOI}
            {\endgroup}
            {%
              \endgroup
              \printfield{doi}%
            }%  
        }%
    }
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
  urldate = {2010-11-22},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
  urldate = {2010-11-22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 - This is much better than my attempt. However, shouldn't there be a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` combo? (And if not, why not?)

Comment: @lockstep. No, I didn't need `\makeatletter` as `\csname` will always construct a control sequence name, even with non-letter tokens (although some may need `\string`, for example active tokens). However, I realised that `biblatex` provides `\thefield`, which avoids the need to access the internal macro at all.

Comment: Just to explain the `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` in the above, I'm keeping `\URLorDOI` local here, so outside of my test it does not exist. This is a good idea in many cases: it would allow me to use an otherwise taken macro name, for example.

Comment: @lockstep, @Joseph: thanks very much, these look marvellous!  I’ll accept one as soon as I’ve tried them out/got them working :-)

Answer (score 14):

I didn't manage to test for "sort-of-identical" `doi` und `url` fields, but here's a solution using [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) - `url` and `urldate` fields will only be typeset if the respective entry doesn't include a `doi` field.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
  urldate = {2010-11-22},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2008.12.003},
  urldate = {2010-11-22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was superbly useful - thank you. I only wish I could find stuff like this by searching the site rather than having to half-write questions first! I have just extended this to print the url iff neither doi nor eprinttype is defined. Seems to work for my simple test case...

Answer (score 6):

*This is really a comment to Joseph Wright's answer above, but with included code.*

I only just now stumbled across this answer (I'm the author of urlbst).

This is great, Joseph -- thanks.  I've incorporated something rather like this into the urlbst repository at https://bitbucket.org/nxg/urlbst, and this should appear in the next release of urlbst (whenever that is).

```
FUNCTION {output.web.refs}
{
  new.block
  inlinelinks
    'skip$ % links were inline -- don't repeat them
    { % If the generated DOI will be the same as the URL,
      % then don't print the URL (thanks to Joseph Wright for this code,
      % at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5660)
      adddoiresolver 
          doiurl doi empty$ { "X" } { doi } if$ * % DOI URL to be generated
          url empty$ { "Y" } { url } if$          % the URL, or "Y" if empty
          =                                       % are the strings equal?
          and
        'skip$
        { output.url }
      if$
      addeprints eprint empty$ not and
        { format.eprint output.nonnull }
        'skip$
      if$
      adddoiresolver doi empty$ not and
        { format.doi output.nonnull }
        'skip$
      if$
      addpubmedresolver pubmed empty$ not and
        { format.pubmed output.nonnull }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

The difference is that this avoids printing the URL if it would equal the DOI, rather than the other way round, and also checks if either or both is empty.

For what it's worth, my response to the initial problem would be to delete the semi-redundant URL field in the .bib file.  I would only have both if the URL gave an alternative (possibly openly available) version of the reference.

Comment: Norman, it there a way to only print isbn/issn if there is no url/doi in BibTeX? Something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76534/biblatex-print-isbn-only-if-doi-is-not-defined

Comment: Not in `urlbst`, but if you're willing to edit your `.bst` file, then something like `isbn url empty$ doi empty$ and and { format.isbn output.nonnull } { format.url output.nonnull format.doi output.nonnull } if$` would (I think; not tested) call the `format.isbn` function only if `url` and `doi` were empty, and call `format.url` and `format.doi` if either is non-empty. The `.bst` file would have to define functions `format.isbn` and `and`. Does that point the way to the logic you need?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I have tried using your ideas, but its not easy to figure out.. I have posted a new question to deal with my problem. Maybe you have time to look at it: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248732/define-bibstyle-output-hierarchy-for-doi-url-isbn-and-issn-in-bibtex]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

When using BibLaTeX, this can be very easily done on the data level, without fuddling with output templates or even changing the .bib file.

Just use the `\iffieldundef{field name}{undefined case}{defined case}` macro:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{url}{}{\clearfield{doi}}%
}
```

Note that this doesn't do the *if DOI and URL are the same* test as suggested by the OP, but just the simpler *only show DOI when there's no URL* case as some of the other answers.

Comment: But then this doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, I know, but there are other answers who don't as well, but which are way more complicated and intrusive, so I think my suggestion is still worth sharing.

Comment: @moewe yes, you're right, I included this. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there's that :/ I retracted my not-an-answer flag to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution, without BST manipulation, can be a sed script that deletes the URL field if followed by a DOI field, or similar.  Worked for me; I have a bib library of dblp bib entries from which I extract the relevant ones with bibtool, and then delete the spurious URL fields with sed.

Here is my sed script, acknowledging https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string for the magic incantation.

```
# First, a magic incantation to turn sed from a line-based editor
# to an editor on the whole input.

1h;2,$H;$!d;g

# Then, the actual command, replacing url=A,doi=B by doi=B

s/\s*url\s*=\s*{[^}]*},\(\s*doi\s*=\s*{[^}]*}\)/\1/g

# Note that \s matches a whitespace character (including \n).
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.