# BibTeX style file with hierachical use of DOI, URL fields

Tags: hyperref, bibtex, urls, doi

My custom BibTeX style currently does almost exactly what I want it to do:

- The title of the paper is a hyperlink, using the URL field in the BibTeX if one is provided, and using http://dx.doi.org/ plus the DOI field if not.
- The DOI (if there is one) is appended to the reference, so people with a print-out can look the references up using it.

The final piece in the puzzle is that I want items which have a URL but no DOI (eg Web references) to print the URL, so that they too can be accessed by people with a paper copy. I'm having some trouble getting the bizarre backwards BST language to do this!

[My current BST file is accessible here.](http://andrewsteele.co.uk/r/thesis-bst/statto.bst)

Thanks!

Comment: This question could be useful:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5660/redundancy-in-bib-file-conditionally-suppress-url-if-same-as-doi