# Biblatex: use doi only if there is no URL

Tags: biblatex, urls, doi

Is there a way to insert a `doi` of an entry only in case it is missing a `URL` field? It happens a lot that the `doi` and `URL` are essentially the same, and inserting them both yields a redundancy. I am using `biblatex` with `biber`.

PS: If you think this goal doesn't make sense please share your thoughts!

Comment: I asked a very similar question a couple of years ago, and got some excellent answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5660/redundancy-in-bib-file-conditionally-suppress-url-if-same-as-doi

Comment: I think it is preferable to use 'doi' in the first place since it is intended to be stable.

Answer (score 23):

You can redefine the bibmacro `doi+eprint+url` so that the `doi` field is printed only if the `url` field is not defined, that is, add the following lines in the preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}{\printfield{doi}}{}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}{\printfield{doi}}{}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kastenholz1,
  hyphenation = {american},
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  indextitle = {Computation of ionic solvation free energies},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  subtitle = {I. The electrostatic potential in molecular liquids},
  journaltitle = jchph,
  volume = {124},
  eid = {124106},
  date = {2006},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  urldate = {2006-10-01},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
}
@article{kastenholz2,
  hyphenation = {american},
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  indextitle = {Computation of ionic solvation free energies},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  subtitle = {I. The electrostatic potential in molecular liquids},
  journaltitle = jchph,
  volume = {124},
  eid = {124106},
  date = {2006},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the two entries are identical except for the `url` field, and if this field is defined, the `doi` field is not printed.

Comment: How can I adapt this to do the opposite, i.e. use DOI if possible, use URL only if there is no DOI?

Comment: @user21155. Define `\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\iffieldundef{doi}{\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}{}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}}
`

Answer (score 19):

You can do this via mapping of datasources.  The `\DeclareSourcemap` command

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url,final]
      \step[fieldset=doi,null]
    }  
  }
}
```

processes any `bibtex` input data and for each item in the bibliograhpy file it executes a number of commands given by `\step`:

- the first step `fieldsource` checks the `url` field

  - the instruction `final` means processing of the current entry is terminated if this field is empty or does not exist
- otherwise the next step `fieldset=doi,null` is executed; this clears the `doi` field, in fact it makes it look as if there was never a `doi` field in the input.

The result of this is that all `biber/biblatex` sees is an entry with either a `url` field or a `doi` field, but not both.

This has the advantage that you don't need to know how the particular `biblatex` style chooses to process these fields.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url,final]
      \step[fieldset=doi,null]
    }  
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Akbulut-S:deformations-G2,
  author =   {Akbulut, Selman and Salur, Sema},
  title =    {Deformations in {$G_2$} manifolds},
  journal =  {Adv. Math.},
  volume =   217,
  year =     2008,
  number =   5,
  pages =    {2130--2140},
  issn =     {0001-8708},
  doi =      {10.1016/j.aim.2007.09.009},
  url =      {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2007.09.009}
}
@Article{Akbulut-S:deformations-G22,
  author =   {Akbulut, Selman and Salur, Sema},
  title =    {Deformations in {$G_2$} manifolds},
  journal =  {Adv. Math.},
  volume =   217,
  year =     2008,
  number =   5,
  pages =    {2130--2140},
  issn =     {0001-8708},
  url =      {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2007.09.009}
}
@Article{Akbulut-S:deformations-G23,
  author =   {Akbulut, Selman and Salur, Sema},
  title =    {Deformations in {$G_2$} manifolds},
  journal =  {Adv. Math.},
  volume =   217,
  year =     2008,
  number =   5,
  pages =    {2130--2140},
  issn =     {0001-8708},
  doi =      {10.1016/j.aim.2007.09.009},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost ;) If in the first `\step` `url` does not exist, then the entry is skipped, the next `\step` is **not** executed and the `\map` ends. Next, the `\map` is started again for the next entry (if one exists). Is this correct? How do you understand this from the manual?

Comment: @Dror Your interpretation is correct.  Most of my understand is from the discussion of the `\step` command in the manual.  It is not the most lucid, but there are a number of examples given afterwards that can help - however there are almost too many examples.  A little experimenting with small examples is also effective.

Comment: Thanks very much! Is this tied to Biber or does this happen inside biblatex regardless of the backend?

Comment: @Eike I haven't tried other backends, but would guess that this should be independent.