# How to merge bibtex number and issue?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have the following:

[image]

Is it a good Idea to merge the

> *Iss. 1* number in [6]  to  *76(1)*

(such that is is more consistent with [7])
or is that no good citation style?

So I like to replace the *number* with the *issue* **if and only** if there is no number defined?  Is that possible?

With the following setting:

```
\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        %citestyle = alphabetic, 
        %bibstyle = ieee-alphabetic,  
        sortlocale=en_US,
        sorting=nyt,
        backref=true,
        hyperref=true,
        firstinits=true,
        style=numeric,%style=alphabetic,
        defernumbers=true,
        isbn=false,
        %eid=true,
        doi=true,
        %series=true,
        eprint=false,
        bibencoding = utf8
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eid}{Art.\addnbspace#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issue}{Iss.\addnbspace#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{Vol.\addnbspace#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \clearfield{month}%
    \clearfield{day}%+
  }{%
  }%
}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154864/biblatex-use-doi-only-if-there-is-no-url
% only URL if no DOI otherwise DOI
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\iffieldundef{doi}{\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}{}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit
}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
    \printlist{institution}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit
}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{%
    \printlist{institution}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit
}

% makes volume of journal bold and adds colon
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
```

Comment: In `biblatex`-speak the `issue` is used for "Summer"/"Spring" etc. designations instead of numbers (for which we should use `number`). So you should probably make your `.bib` file conform to this rule. You can of course let Biber do that for you if you want.

Comment: ahh thanks!, how to do this, with biber?

Answer (score 11):

[The `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has the following to say about the `issue` field (p. 19):

> The issue of a journal. This field is intended for journals whose
>   individual issues are identified by a designation such as ‘Spring’ or
>   ‘Summer’ rather than the month or a number. Since the placement of
>   issue is similar to `month` and `number`, this field may also be
>   useful with double issues and other special cases.

So you should use the `number` field in this case

```
@article{PhysRevE.76.011301,
  title = {Force transmission in a packing of pentagonal particles},
  author = {Azéma, Emilien and Radjaï, Farhang and Peyroux, Robert and Saussine, Gilles},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {76},
  number = {1},
  pages = {011301},
  date = {2007-07},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.76.011301},
}
```

If you cannot do that (you should really, though) you can use Biber's sourcemapping to do that for you

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=issue, match=\regexp{\A(\d+)\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=number, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=issue, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This copies the `issue` to the `number` field if the former contains only digits and then deletes the `issue` field.

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{PhysRevE.76.011301,
  title = {Force transmission in a packing of pentagonal particles},
  author = {Azéma, Emilien and Radjaï, Farhang and Peyroux, Robert and Saussine, Gilles},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {76},
  issue = {1},
  pages = {011301},
  date = {2007-07},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.76.011301},
}
@article{PhysRevE.86.031303,
  title = {Discrete simulation of dense flows of polyhedral grains down a rough inclined plane},
  author = {Azéma, Emilien and Descantes, Yannick and Roquet, Nicolas and Roux, Jean-Noël and Chevoir, François},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {86},
  number = {3},
  pages = {031303},
  date = {2012-06},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.86.031303},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=issue, match=\regexp{\A(\d+)\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=number, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=issue, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: aw men, this is crazy awesome, appreciate you showed how to do this!

Comment: @Gabriel If the answer helped you you are of course very welcome to accept it.