# "Author (in prep.)" instead of "Author (year)"

Tags: biblatex

## Issue

I would like to be able to cite works that are in preparation but still incomplete, using "in prep." instead of a date. (This is mainly for citing my own work in progress in job applications, my CV, etc.) The reason is because (at least in my field) "Bar (2016)" implies that the work is at least somewhat complete and available in some form or other (published, or posted on an archive or the author's website), whereas "Bar (in prep.)" does not imply either one.

Specifically, I would like to be able to do something like the following with Biblatex:

```
\cite{bar}         -> Bar [in prep.]
\textcite{bar}     -> Bar (in prep.)
\parencite{bar}    -> (Bar [in prep.])
\printbibliography -> Bar, Foo (in prep.). Title. ...
```

I don't think the square brackets are conventional, but they make sense to me because "Bar in prep." and "(Bar in prep.)" look odd, especially with more than one author, e.g. "Bar and Baz in prep.", and "Bar (in prep.)" is already taken and has a different semantics.

Biblatex has a field called `pubstate` that accepts the possible value `inpreparation`, which gets expanded to the (localized) string "in preparation". By default, however, if I also specify a date, then the date gets printed instead of "in preparation".

```
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  date = {2016},
  pubstate = {inpreparation},
  title = {Title},
}

\cite{bar}         -> Bar 2016
\textcite{bar}     -> Bar (2016)
\parencite{bar}    -> (Bar 2016)
\printbibliography -> Bar, Foo (2016). Title. ... In preparation.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  date = {2016},
  pubstate = {inpreparation},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
In \cite{bar}, \textcite{bar} argues \ldots \parencite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here are two solutions I know of.

## Solution #1

Replace `date = {2016}` with `year = {in prep.}`. (NB: Using `date = {in prep.}` throws an error.) This kind of works, but is not exactly what I'm looking for (no square brackets). Moreover, it's an abuse of the `year` field, and I would prefer a semantically better solution in the spirit of Biblatex.

```
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  year = {in prep.},
  title = {Title},
}

\cite{bar}         -> Bar in prep.
\textcite{bar}     -> Bar (in prep.)
\parencite{bar}    -> (Bar in prep.)
\printbibliography -> Bar, Foo (in prep.). Title. ...
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  year = {in prep.},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
In \cite{bar}, \textcite{bar} argues \ldots \parencite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Solution #2

Remove the `date` field altogether, keep `pubstate = {inpreparation}`, and add

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{pubstate}
}
```

which basically means "use `date`, if there is a value for it; otherwise, use `pubstate`, if there is a value for it".

```
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  pubstate = {inpreparation},
  title = {Title},
}

\cite{bar}         -> Bar in preparation
\textcite{bar}     -> Bar (in preparation)
\parencite{bar}    -> (Bar in preparation)
\printbibliography -> Bar, Foo. Title. ... In preparation.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  pubstate = {inpreparation},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{pubstate}
}

\begin{document}
In \cite{bar}, \textcite{bar} argues \ldots \parencite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This solution is more in line with Biblatex principles, but it's still a bit off:

- "in preparation" instead of the shorter (and more conventional) "in prep."
- no square brackets in `\cite` and `\parencite` cases
- no "(in prep.)" immediately after the author in the reference list

## My question

Is there any easy way to adapt solution #2 (or similar) so that `inpreparation` expands to "in prep.", to add square brackets but only for `\cite` and `\parencite`, and to add "(in prep.)" (or "in prep." or whatever, in accordance with the specified `bibstyle`) after the author name in the reference list?

Or is there a better way of going about all of this that I've overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for "Bar and Baz in prep." :) Seriously, your question interests me very much, I had the same problem yesterday, answering a question, and I opt for Solution #1, but I'm looking forward to finding a smartiest solution!

Comment: You're using biblatex so suppressing one field (`date`) when another is populated(`inpreparation`) is quite easy ([an example with DOIs and URLs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154872/28808)).  More generally, it will be possible to do this nicely (but I lack the expertise to help you without spending time I haven't got).

Comment: @CarLaTeX: There are some other problems with solution #1, which I didn't mention. For example, Biblatex eats up punctuation following "in prep.", which is good when it's a period because you don't want two periods in a row, but bad when it's a comma, semicolon, etc. Try `In \cite{bar}, blah`. Another problem is that, because of this, Biblatex essentially treats the period in "in prep." as a sentence-final period, thus sometimes adding too much space afterwards. Compare: `\noindent xxx \cite{bar} xxx\\ xxx Bar in prep.~xxx` The first has more space than the second.

Comment: @BrianBuccola Probably with `\adddot` and some other tricks thay can be solved, let's wait for some expert's answer!

Comment: @BrianBuccola P.S. = in my case the words were "in press" not "in prep.", so the dot problem wasn't relevant...

Comment: If you are worried by the error in solution #1: with an additional `sortyear = 2016` the error should be removed in upcoming versions of biblatex

Comment: Why do you want to include a `date` field in an entry for something currently in preparation? This seems odd to me.

Comment: @cfr If you don't include any date, then Biblatex prints "n.d." (standing for "no date"), e.g. "Bar (n.d.) argues ..." Solution #1 is to brute-force printing "(in prep.)" by setting `year = {in prep.}`. Solution #2 is to not include any `date` (or `year`) field at all, and then tell Biblatex to print the value of `pubstate` instead. So, it's not that I "want to include a `date` field"; it's that if I don't include one, the result is very undesirable, unless I incorporate the workaround of solution #2. Unless I've misunderstood you, or you have a better suggestion...?

Comment: My point is that solution #2 makes much better sense in Biblatex terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a reasonable, but somewhat limited, solution for the question.

In order to have the shorter form "in prep." instead of the full one, you can:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    inpreparation      = {in prep\adddot},
}
```

As you suggested yourself, to add `pubstate` to the `labeldate`:

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
    \field{date}
    \field{year}
    \field{eventdate}
    \field{origdate}
    \field{urldate}
    \field{pubstate}   % <-- NEW
    \literal{nodate}
}
```

To get the square brackets in `\cite` and `\parencite` I believe the simplest way is to adjust the respective cite commands:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{\thefield{labelyear}}}}}{}%   <-- NEW
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{\thefield{labelyear}}}}}{}%   <-- NEW
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

(@CarLaTeX, I don't see why this shouldn't work with "in press" too).

To get "(in prep.)" in the place of the year in the bibliography:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
      {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{\thefield{pubstate}}}}{}}   % <-- NEW
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
           {\printdateextralabel}%
           {\printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}}}}%
```

Given this, if you wish to omit the redundant "In preparation" at the end of the reference in the bibliography:

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{}{\printfield{pubstate}}}   % <-- NEW
```

Putting it all together in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{bar,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  pubstate = {inpreparation},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    inpreparation      = {in prep\adddot},
}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
    \field{date}
    \field{year}
    \field{eventdate}
    \field{origdate}
    \field{urldate}
    \field{pubstate}  % <-- NEW
    \literal{nodate}
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{\thefield{labelyear}}}}}{}%  <-- NEW
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{\thefield{labelyear}}}}}{}%  <-- NEW
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{}{\printfield{pubstate}}}   % <-- NEW

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
      {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpreparation}{\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{\thefield{pubstate}}}}{}}  % <-- NEW
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
           {\printdateextralabel}%
           {\printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}}}}%

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
In \cite{bar}, \textcite{bar} argues \ldots\ \parencite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image]

But, alas, the limitation is quite restrictive. If you have two or more "in preps." from the same author, you will get strange results in the dealing of the `extrayear` part. But this would also be the case in both of the 2 solutions of the OP (least bad with solution #1).