# Non-year citations in ShareLatex/Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am compiling a document on sharelatex.com. I would like to have a citation like "Smith (in press)". However, since I cannot edit the bibliography style's bst file online, I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried the solution with `\noop` mentioned here, but it didn't work. [How to enter publications "in press", or "submitted to" in BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31384/how-to-enter-publications-in-press-or-submitted-to-in-bibtex)

I am using the default ShareLaTeX settings, where it's compiled with pdflatex.

The bibtex file includes

```
@preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " }

@unpublished{degen2016definitely,
  title={Definitely, maybe: Approaching speaker commitment experimentally},
  author={Degen, Judith and Scontras, Gregory and Trotzke, Andreas and Wittenberg, Eva},
  note={in revision},
  year={\noop{2016}in revision}
}
```

In the main file, I have the following packages loaded, and call the bibliography as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xparse} % for the main command
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{adam.bib}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about your set-up please? Your question does not mention which bibliography package you use explicitly. Since you mention `.bst` files and `\noop` and link to a BibTeX question, that makes me think you use BibTeX. But you have tagged your question `biblatex`. `biblatex` and BibTeX are fundamentally incompatible. Please show us a full [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)/[MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), so we can really see what is going on at your end.

Comment: I second moewe's demand for more details. But, in case you are considering `biblatex` as an alternative, you could look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367423/105447 for a start.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I added some details. How can I tell if sharelatex is using bibtex or biblatex?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using `biblatex` as the bibliography package instead of `natbib`. In addition, the package `gb4e` has been known to create some issues. Finally, with `biblatex` I used the `\textcite` and `\parencite` commands in place of `\cite`.

Comment: Couldn't come earlier back here. Anyway, good to know you found your way through with `biblatex`.