# Suppress URL if DOI is present in biblatex-chicago

Tags: bibliographies, conditionals, urls, doi, biblatex-chicago

This question is probably a home-run for people that are more into the workings of biblatex than me...
Anyway, I want to achieve what has been solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154864/67042) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5660), but with using `biblatex-chicago` instead of `biblatex`. That means the URL should be suppressed whenever a DOI is present in the reference. Note: In the original questions it was the other way round.

The [MWE of karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154872/67042) will not work as soon as I replace `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}{\printfield{doi}}{}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kastenholz1,
  hyphenation = {american},
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  indextitle = {Computation of ionic solvation free energies},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  subtitle = {I. The electrostatic potential in molecular liquids},
  journaltitle = jchph,
  volume = {124},
  eid = {124106},
  date = {2006},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  urldate = {2006-10-01},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
}
@article{kastenholz2,
  hyphenation = {american},
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  indextitle = {Computation of ionic solvation free energies},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  subtitle = {I. The electrostatic potential in molecular liquids},
  journaltitle = jchph,
  volume = {124},
  eid = {124106},
  date = {2006},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: not good]

Who can help, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, wouldn't adding the option

```
\usepackage[doi=only]{biblatex-chicago}
```

or

```
\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

work (the latter would suppress *all* URLs)? See 4.4.2 in [the `biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. The idea was to suppress the URL *only if* a DOI is present.

Comment: Yes, the 'doi=only' option should do that. Just tested it; works here.

Comment: sorry. cannot test right now.  and it still shows the url if no doi is present? sounds good.

Comment: It should. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: By the way, please accept answer as correct if it works for you. It helps others find/identify the solution when they have the same problem.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it requires less tinkering. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can patch the two macros responsible for printing the `doi` and the `url` to clear the `url` field if there is a `doi` defined:

```
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% patch macro used in bibliography
\xpretobibmacro{bib+doi+url}
  {\iffieldundef{doi}
     {}
     {\clearfield{url}}}
  {}{}

% patch macro used in notes
\xpretobibmacro{cite+doi+url}
  {\iffieldundef{doi}
     {}
     {\clearfield{url}}}
  {}{}
```