# Bibtex: Remove URL if DOI is present and keyword does not exist

Tags: biblatex, biber, filter

This question is highly related to:
[Biblatex: use doi only if there is no URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154864/biblatex-use-doi-only-if-there-is-no-url/154872)

However, I cannot get it to work for my example. I have the following setup. Most of my bib entries contain DOI, URL, and sometimes keywords (not always present). I want to remove (ignore) the URL if the DOI is present and the keywords do not contain the word "primary". In other words, if it's a primary source, don't remove anything.

I set up a `biber.conf`, since its easier, which looks like this:

```xml
<config><sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
        <map map_overwrite="1"> 
            <map_step map_field_source="doi" map_final="1"/>
            <map_step map_field_source="keywords" map_match=".*primary.*" map_final="1"/>
            <map_step map_field_set="url" map_null="1"/>
        </map>
    </maps>
</sourcemap></config>
```

Surprisingly, this does not work. It does exactly the opposite instead. Now URL is removed if the "primary" keyword exists. I found this really counterintuitive. So I tried the opposite and changed `map_match` to `map_notmatch`. This works, but not always. I noticed that the URL is properly removed but only if the `keywords` entry exists. If there is no `keywords` field in the bib entry at all, the URL is not filtered (see the MWE below).

```xml
<map_step map_field_source="keywords" map_notmatch=".*primary.*" map_final="1"/>
```

Now, this does not make any sense to me. If the keywords contain "primary" we terminate with `map_final` but if there is no `keywords` field at all, we do not terminate? So I tried to add an additional map step to check if the `keywords` exist but it does not work either. Can someone please help?

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% kastenholz1 URL is not filtered... WHY? (maybe because no keywords field is present?)
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kastenholz1,
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
}
@article{kastenholz2,
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
  keywords = {secondary}
}
@article{kastenholz3,
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
}
@article{kastenholz4,
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and H{\"u}nenberger, Philippe H.},
  title = {Computation of methodology\hyphen independent ionic solvation free
    energies from molecular simulations},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2172593},
  keywords = {primary}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

biber.conf

```xml
<config>
<sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
        <map map_overwrite="1"> 
            <map_step map_field_source="doi" map_final="1"/>
            <map_step map_field_source="keywords" map_notmatch=".*primary.*" map_final="1"/>
            <map_step map_field_set="url" map_null="1"/>
        </map>
    </maps>
</sourcemap>
</config>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This question is titled `Bibtex` but it seems to be about biblatex / biber. I don't think anything here is relevant for people using plain old bibtex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcome of the mapping step of the first `biber.conf` shown in the question is not unexpected.

The keyword `final` means that the following steps are only carried out if the condition of this step is satisfied. For `map_step map_field_source="doi" map_final="1"` that means that the field `doi` must exist. For `map_step map_field_source="keywords" map_match=".*primary.*" map_final="1"` that means that the contents of the `keywords` field must match the regular expression `.*primary.*` (i.e. if the field contains the substring `primary`). Hence, in our example we delete only DOIs of primary sources.

`notmatch` gets us closer to what we want, but unfortunately `notmatch` is false if the field in question does not exist. This means we can't easily get things done in one mapping.

I suggest you use two mappings:

- the first mapping clears out the URL if there is no `keyword` at all
- the second mapping clears out the URL if the `keyword` is present, but does not match `primary`.

In the MWE below I use `\DeclareSourcemap` instead of `biber.conf`, because that makes the example more self-contained (plus, I find the `\DeclareSourcemap` syntax easier to work with). If you need help with the relevant `xml` syntax, have a look at the `.bcf` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[notfield = keywords, final]
      \step[fieldsource = doi, final]
      \step[fieldset = url, null]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = keywords, notmatch = \regexp{\bprimary\b}, final]
      \step[fieldsource = doi, final]
      \step[fieldset = url, null]
    }
  }
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kastenholz1,
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and Hünenberger, Philippe H.},
  title  = {URL + DOI},
  url    = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  doi    = {10.1063/1.2172593},
}
@article{kastenholz2,
  author   = {Kastenholz, M. A. and Hünenberger, Philippe H.},
  title    = {URL + DOI // secondary},
  url      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  doi      = {10.1063/1.2172593},
  keywords = {secondary},
}
@article{kastenholz3,
  author = {Kastenholz, M. A. and Hünenberger, Philippe H.},
  title  = {URL},
  url    = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
}
@article{kastenholz4,
  author   = {Kastenholz, M. A. and Hünenberger, Philippe H.},
  title    = {URL + DOI // primary},
  url      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593},
  doi      = {10.1063/1.2172593},
  keywords = {primary},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] M. A. Kastenholz and Philippe H. Hünenberger. “URL”. In: (). url: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593. [2] M. A. Kastenholz and Philippe H. Hünenberger. “URL + DOI”. In: (). doi:10.1063/1.2172593. [3] M. A. Kastenholz and Philippe H. Hünenberger. “URL + DOI // primary”.In: (). doi: 10.1063/1.2172593. url: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2172593. [4] M. A. Kastenholz and Philippe H. Hünenberger. “URL + DOI // secondary”. In: (). doi: 10.1063/1.2172593.]

Comment: That makes sense. I was always trying to solve it within one map and added new steps to correct the previous errors. But that messed it up completely. The two map solution is probably the cleanest. Thank you very much.