# biber tool mode: Extract all entries that include a specific keyword into a new .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

## Problem statement

I am looking for a way to use [`biber`](https://texdoc.org/serve/biber.pdf/0)'s "tool mode" to run a (CLI) command on a large `.bib` file in order to

1. extract from it only those entries whose `keywords = {}` field includes a user-definable value (such as `mykeyword` in the example below), and
2. write the resulting entries to a new `.bib` file.

## Example

Imagine a `.bib` file with the following entries:

```
@article{First,
    [...]
    keywords = {foo, bla},
}

@article{Second,
    [...]
    keywords = {test, foo},
}

@article{Third,
    [...]
    keywords = {bla},
}
```

Running the "magic command" I am looking for on this `.bib` file would match the following entries:

- for keyword `foo`: `First` and `Second`
- for keyword `bla`: `First` and `Third`
- for keyword `test`: `Second`

## What I am *not* looking for

- For a variety of reasons beyond the scope of this question, I would like to really use `biber`'s "tool mode" to solve this problem (rather than other tools such as `bibexport`, `bib2bib`, or `bibtool`).
- I am  looking for a solution that uses a `.conf` file for `biber`'s "tool mode" and does *not* rely on any `.tex` file in the process.

## Minimal (non-)working example

The [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415593/38212) to [a related problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415584/biblatex-extract-all-entries-of-a-given-type-say-book-into-a-new-bib-file) uses `biber`'s "tool mode" to extract `.bib` entries by document type (rather than by matched keywords). Specifically, it seems to use a customized biber `.conf` file to identify entries that are *not* books via `<per_nottype>` and then exclude those from the bibliography via `<map_step map_entry_null="1" />`.

However, no equivalent `<per_notkeyword>` tag seems to exist, which is why I am guessing my solution would have to rely on some combination of `map_field_set` and `map_field_value`. The following (very ad-hoc!) example does not work as expected, though (not even for the somewhat simpler 'reverse' case it tries to implement for now, i.e., *removing* those entries that include the `mykeyword` keyword):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
          <map>
                <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="mykeyword"/>
                <map_step map_entry_null="1" />
          </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Is there a way to amend the above `.conf` file for `biber` such as to get the desired result?

## Bonus points (not really)

An added bonus would be a generic solution, which allows me to specify the target keyword(s?) as a command-line argument, while relying on only a single `.conf` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shell script solves all aspects of the problem, including the ability to pass the desired keyword as a command-line argument. Note that it only accepts a *single* keyword, which can, however, contain spaces (as long as the keyword is enclosed by double quotes in the script call).

## Shell script `bibextract.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
# Write temporary config file
# NOTE: Escapes " to \" and replaces $2 by second command-line argument

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<config>
    <output_align>true</output_align>
    <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
    <sourcemap>

        <!-- Main source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616241/38212 -->
        <maps datatype=\"bibtex\">

            <!-- Step 1: Remove all entries that do not contain any keywords whatsoever (necessary because later 'map_notmatch' is FALSE in that case) -->
            <map>
                <map_step map_notfield=\"keywords\" map_final=\"1\"/>   <!-- map_final=\"1\" means that next step is only executed if this condition is met -->
                <map_step map_entry_null=\"1\"/>                        <!-- remove entry from output -->
            </map>

            <!-- Step 2: From remaining entries, remove any where keyword does /not/ match regular expression -->
            <map>
                <map_step map_field_source=\"keywords\" map_notmatch=\".*${2}.*\" map_final=\"1\"/>
                <map_step map_entry_null=\"1\"/>
            </map>

        </maps>

    </sourcemap>
</config>" > /tmp/by_keyword.conf
  
# Run biber in "tool mode" using that temporary config file
biber --tool --configfile=/tmp/by_keyword.conf --output-file $3 $1
    
# Clean up
rm $1.blg
rm /tmp/by_keyword.conf
    
exit 0
```

1. Save to `./bibextract.sh`
2. Make executable: `chmod +x ./bibextract.sh`

## Usage

```bash
$ ./bibextract.sh input.bib  mykeyword output.bib
$ ./bibextract.sh input.bib  "my keyword with spaces" output.bib
```

## Explanation

The script first writes a temporary configuration file for `biber`'s "tool mode" to `/tmp/by_keyword.conf`, which implements a two-step mapping process inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616241/38212):

1. Remove all entries that do not contain any keywords whatsoever (necessary because later `map_notmatch` is `FALSE` in that case)
2. From remaining entries, remove any where keyword does *not* match regular expression (essentially `.*my keyword with spaces.*`)

Biber is then run in "tool mode" using that config, after which the temporary config file (and a `.blg` file created in the process) are deleted again.

## Example `test.bib` to test script with

```
@book{FooBla,
    title = {FooBla},
    author = {FooBla},
    keywords = {foo, bla},
}

@article{MooFoo,
    title = {MooFoo},
    author = {MooFoo},
    keywords = {moo, foo},
}

@misc{Bla,
    title = {Bla},
    author = {Bla},
    keywords = {bla},
}

@book{BlaThe-WordFoo,
    title = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
    author = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
    keywords = {bla, the word, foo},
}

@collection{NoKeywords,
    title = {NoKeywords},
    author = {NoKeywords},
}
```

## Testing routine

```bash
$ ./bibextract.sh test.bib foo foo.bib
$ ./bibextract.sh test.bib bla bla.bib
$ ./bibextract.sh test.bib moo moo.bib
$ ./bibextract.sh test.bib "the word" the-word.bib
```

## Resulting `.bib` files

### `foo.bib`

```
@book{FooBla,
  author   = {FooBla},
  keywords = {foo,bla},
  title    = {FooBla},
}

@article{MooFoo,
  author   = {MooFoo},
  keywords = {moo,foo},
  title    = {MooFoo},
}

@book{BlaThe-WordFoo,
  author   = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
  keywords = {bla,the word,foo},
  title    = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
}
```

### `bla.bib`

```
@book{FooBla,
  author   = {FooBla},
  keywords = {foo,bla},
  title    = {FooBla},
}

@misc{Bla,
  author   = {Bla},
  keywords = {bla},
  title    = {Bla},
}

@book{BlaThe-WordFoo,
  author   = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
  keywords = {bla,the word,foo},
  title    = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
}
```

### `moo.bib`

```
@article{MooFoo,
  author   = {MooFoo},
  keywords = {moo,foo},
  title    = {MooFoo},
}
```

### `the-word.bib`

```
@book{BlaThe-WordFoo,
  author   = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
  keywords = {bla,the word,foo},
  title    = {BlaThe-WordFoo},
}
```

Comment: This is nice but note that it is unlikely to be secure or portable. (These things may not matter at all in your case, but they might if somebody else wants to use your script.)

Comment: I added syntax highlighting to the bash stuff. Please revert if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax coloring, that was indeed the idea. Regarding portability & security: yes, I first had planned to only provide .conf file and biber command, without a shell script, but the latter was the only method I could think of for getting an argument ($2, that is, which represents the keyword) into that .conf file. I'd be happy to consider other ways to achieve that goal, though.

Comment: It wasn't really a criticism. Mostly in case somebody else wanted to use it. I believe that `echo`, for example, isn't very portable and a secure script would do more checking on arguments etc. But I don't really see why you should worry about those things so long as it works for you.