# bibtex: URL and DOI line breaks on different characters

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, line-breaking, doi

In my references, I want to allow DOI's to break on a slash '/' character (or as a last resort on any character) to avoid underfull lines like the third reference below. Note that URL's are already breaking on slashes, and DOI's are already breaking on dashes.

[image: image with problematic entry]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}
\urlstyle{rm}
\bibliographystyle{sp}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Endriss:09} \nocite{Evans:80} \nocite{Szabolcsi:10}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Here are some .bib entries:

```
@article{Evans:80, Author={Gareth Evans}, Journal={Linguistic Inquiry}, Number={2},
    Pages={337--362}, Title={Pronouns}, Url={http://www.jstor.org/stable/4178164},
    Volume={11}, Year={1980}}

@book{Szabolcsi:10, Author={Anna Szabolcsi}, Doi={10.1017/CBO9780511781681},
    Publisher={Cambridge University Press}, Title={Quantification}, Year={2010}}
```

The bibliography style file can be downloaded as part of a zip file (containing also the actually used class file) here: [Instructions for S&P authors using LATEX 2ε | von Fintel | Semantics and Pragmatics](http://semprag.org/article/view/sp.0.2).

Comment: Adding `\penalty 0` to the .bbl file manually produces a break, but messes up the link destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the “doi:” also in roman font, as it seems to me, you need to replace the package `doi` with an own command `\doi` declared with `url`’s own facilities. It doesn’t matter, that it’s already defined in the class file `sp.cls`. Otherwise you could also use the package `uri`. Compare also my answer here: [Produce a hyperlinked DOI?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50528/9237).

```
\documentclass{sp} % based on "article"

\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% will produce a BIB file with the same name like your main tex file
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Evans:80,
  Author={Gareth Evans},
  Journal={Linguistic Inquiry},
  Number={2},
  Pages={337--362},
  Title={Pronouns},
  Url={http://www.jstor.org/stable/4178164},
  Volume={11}, Year={1980}
}
@book{Szabolcsi:10,
  Author={Anna Szabolcsi},
  Doi={10.1017/CBO9780511781681},
  Publisher={Cambridge University Press},
  Title={Quantification},
  Year={2010}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib} % actually not needed: already defined in the class "sp"
\bibliographystyle{sp} % actually not needed: already defined in the class "sp"


% already loaded with the class "sp", throws out an error, if separately loaded:
% \usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} % loads "url"
%
\urlstyle{rm} % actually not needed: already defined in the class "sp"
% see the documentation of "url" for the next command
% "doi:" is not part of the link:
\DeclareUrlCommand\doi{\def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{doi:\href{http://dx.doi.org/##1}{##1}}\urlstyle{rm}}
% "doi:" is part of the link:
% \DeclareUrlCommand\doi{\def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{\href{http://dx.doi.org/##1}{doi:##1}}\urlstyle{rm}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Evans:80} \nocite{Szabolcsi:10}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick!  (Using package `uri` almost worked, except that “doi:” became part of the link.)

Comment: Note, though, that this will not parse the doi for unwanted characters such as `<`, `>` and `;` , as the `doi` package does.

Comment: @episanty In `doi.sty` explicitly is written: “Some publishers have elected to use some nasty characters in their doi numbering scheme (<, >, ; have all been spotted).” For an example with semicolon see my linked answer.