# Citation with DOI that has underscore breaks functionality in BibDesk

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, doi, bibdesk

One functionality of BibDesk that is nice is the ability to click on a link at the end of the `Doi` entry field, which will open up the link `http://dx.doi.org/DOI-HERE` in a browser.

[image]

One problem I've just run into with bibliography styles that display DOIs in the References section (e.g., [`unified`](http://celxj.org/downloads/unified.bst)) is that a `Doi` entry that contains an underscore will be printed as a subscript in the References section.

For example, this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{chomsky1977b}
\citet{chomsky1977b-test}

\bibliographystyle{unified}
\bibliography{master}

\end{document}
```

produces this output

[image]

where `chomsky1977b` is

```
@article{chomsky1977b,
    Author = {Chomsky, Noam and Lasnik, Howard},
    Doi = {10.1007/978-94-015-6859-3_4},
    Journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
    Keywords = {control theory, syntax},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {425-504},
    Title = {Filters and Control},
    Volume = {8},
    Year = {1977}}
```

and `chomsky1997b-test` is

```
@article{chomsky1977b-test,
    Author = {Chomsky, Noam and Lasnik, Howard},
    Doi = {10.1007/978-94-015-6859-3{\_}4},
    Journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
    Keywords = {control theory, syntax},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {425-504},
    Title = {Filters and Control},
    Volume = {8},
    Year = {1977}}
```

Of course, the `Doi` entry in `chomsky1997b-test` breaks the BibDesk functionality of opening the link in a browser, as it opens `http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-015-6859-3{\_}4` rather than `http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-015-6859-3_4`.

Is there a way to retain this functionality yet still ensure that the DOI is printed correctly in the References section when using a style that prints the DOI?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For your particular example (of the `unified.bst`) style, it suffices to add the following line to your preamble (and load the `hyperref` package)

```
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\textsc{doi}: \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{chomsky1977b,
    Author = {Chomsky, Noam and Lasnik, Howard},
    Doi = {10.1007/978-94-015-6859-3_4},
    Journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
    Keywords = {control theory, syntax},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {425-504},
    Title = {Filters and Control},
    Volume = {8},
    Year = {1977}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\textsc{doi}: \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\citet{chomsky1977b}

\bibliographystyle{unified}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

then yields
[image]

Comment: One has to note though that while this solution works in this particular example, it cannot be universally applied. It really depends on how printing the DOI is implemented in the `.bst` file. One certainly has to have a look at the `.bst` file to find out whether printing is implemented via a dedicated command (as was done here with `\doi{foo}`) or directly; in the latter case it will (probably) be necessary to edit the `.bst` file.

Comment: This is nice, but only if using the unified style. For conferences where styles are given and cannot be modified, there is no easy fix.

Comment: @peschü That's pretty much what my comment above said as well. If you have a conference style that you can't modify you would probably expect that that style gives the required output...

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315666/188244) to similar issue by Roly in [Missing $ inserted issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71215/missing-inserted-issue), who recommends to use `\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`.

The package arranges that, while in text, ‘_’ itself behaves as \textunderscore (the behaviour of _ in maths mode is not affected).

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you look at your `.bst`, i.e. the BibTeX style file, there should be a function formating the DOI output.

There you could use `\href`from the `hyperref` package and `\detokenize` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50023/produce-a-hyperlinked-doi) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography), you can do something like

```
FUNCTION {format.doilink}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ doi empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "{,\ doi:~\href{http://dx.doi.org/" * doi * "}{\detokenize{" * doi * "}}}" * }
  if$
}
if$
}
```

which is based on the naming used in style files of the elsevier BibTeX files, so your function in the `.bst` file might differ in naming. The function above pouts a “doi:” in front, as your example suggests. So you could just search your style file for that and change the output after that.

Comment: + 1, though I think I will accept the other answer, as it does not require modifying the `.bst` file. Also, as a side note, for some reason I have to load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` when compiling, otherwise `\detokenize{_}` is rendered as what seems to be [`U+05C4`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05c4/index.htm). One last note, I assume you mean `hyperref` and not `hyperlink`?

Comment: Yep, I should've added an MWE, of course you neet `T1`and of course i meant hyperref. I edited my answer. The advantage of this solution, it also works for styles not using a `\doi` command (mine had not even an idea of handling doi entries. But of course, editing a `.bst` might not be that much fun ;)

Comment: So it seems. I just asked about that [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150767/strange-behaviour-with-detokenize-and-underscore). I didn't realize `OT1` was the default for LaTeX. Silly me. Anyway, thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [doi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doi) package. It provides a `\doi` command that handles all sorts of nasty characters.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue. My solution was to use `\textunderscore` inplace of `_`.

Comment: As I explained in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643285/250119), `\textunderscore` is just an uselessly-long way to write `\_`.