# Where does BibDesk store its BibTeX style sheets?

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

Where are the BibTeX style sheets that can be used by "Preferences -> TeX preview" in BibDesk?

I would like to add my own.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My understanding is that so long as the `.bst` file is somewhere where a normal TeX distro would find it (such as in `TEXMFHOME`), then you should be able to use it. You will just have to type the full name of the `.bst` file yourself.

Comment: When I put it in `texmf` and enter the full name, I get an error. Do I have to configure my Tex distro somehow? I'm using BibDesk with Pages.

Comment: Is it in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/` or just `~/Library/texmf/`?

Comment: The first, i.e. `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/`. And I have TexShop installed.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. That's how things are set up for me, and it works fine.

Comment: BibDesk tells me my .bst file is not one of the 8 standard files and tells me I might have to edit it. When I click on edit, this Excalibur software starts and shows me a tex file that probably comes from BibDesk.

Comment: You don't need to edit it. Here, I'll post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for BibDesk to use a particular style file in its TeX preview, the `.bst` file only needs to be somewhere where a normal TeX distribution can find it, such as in `TEXMFHOME`. Since we're talking about a Mac here (because of BibDesk), this usually means that it needs to be in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/`.

(If you do not know how to set up the `TEXMFHOME` folder, see Alan Munn's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8359/32888) to [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/32888).)

Once you have your local `TEXMFHOME` folder set up with the correct directory structure, place the `.bst` file that you would like to use in BibDesk's TeX preview in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/`.

Next, you need to change the `.bst` file that BibDesk uses. You can do this by going to BibDesk > Preferences, or by just hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> when you have BibDesk open. Click on TeX Preview, where you will this screen:

[image]

You need to change the BibTeX style to whichever `.bst` file that you would like to use. For example, I use a custom `.bst` file called `unified`, so I would change `apalike` to say `unified`. After I type `unified` and hit enter, I see this screen come up:

[image]

You can go ahead and just click on `Use Anyway`, and everything should work just fine. Clicking `Edit TeX template` allows you to edit the preamble of the `.tex` file that renders the TeX preview in BibDesk. When I click `Edit TeX template`, it opens the preamble in TeXShop, since that is my default TeX editor.

This isn't strictly necessary and, like I said, you can just go ahead and click `Use Anyway` and things should work fine.

However, it can be useful to edit the TeX template. For example, the `unified.bst` file that I use typesets DOIs, but there are many DOIs that contain an underscore, which causes an error.

So, I have edited the TeX template to include the following in the preamble (see [Citation with DOI that has underscore breaks functionality in BibDesk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149086/32888)):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\textsc{doi}: \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

But again, you should be able to just hit `Use Anyway` and have things work so long as your `.bst` file is somewhere where a normal TeX distribution would be able to see it (such as in the `TEXMFHOME` folder) **and** so long as your `.bst` file doesn't depend on any other packages/macros. If the functionality of the `.bst` file depends on other packages/macros, then you will necessarily have to edit the TeX template and include those in the preamble of the TeX template.

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you very much. I had the texmf folder in the wrong library directory.

Comment: This is a great answer, but note that a more succinct version is also found in BibDesk's Help book, easily accessible via its Help menu. Hint, hint :). http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDeskHelp_65.html#SEC125