# How to escape characters within variables used in command definitions?

Tags: macros, natbib, doi, renewcommand

I want the doi part of my references (in APA style) to look like this:

`doi: <hyperlinked doi>`

To achieve this I've added the command `\renewcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}` after `\usepackage{doi}`. This works without issue 99% of the time, but when it comes to dois that have underscores in them, I get the compile error:

`Missing $ inserted. ...PACrefDOI} \doi{problem_doi}`.

The only way I've found to fix this is by manually escaping the underscores in my .bbl file. I've hoped, however, that there may be a way of tweaking my doi command so it automatically escapes underscores for me. Here is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}
\renewcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \cite{notaraParentalWeightStatus2019}
    \bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

where mwe.bib contains:

```
@article{notaraParentalWeightStatus2019,
  title         = {Parental Weight Status and Early Adolescence Body Weight in Association with Socioeconomic Factors},
  author        = {Notara, Venetia and Magriplis, Emmanuella and Prapas, Christos and Antonogeorgos, George and {Rojas-Gil}, Andrea Paola and Kornilaki, Ekaterina N. and Lagiou, Areti and Panagiotakos, Demosthenes B.},
  year          = {2019},
  journal       = {Journal of Education and Health Promotion},
  volume        = {8},
  pages         = {77},
  issn          = {2277-9531},
  doi           = {10.4103/jehp.jehp_14_19},
  abstract      = {BACKGROUND: Childhood obesity remains a major health issue. The understanding of the multifactorial nature of childhood obesity remains the cornerstone to eliminate the rising trends. This study aimed to examine the association between parental and childhood weight status, in relation to various socioeconomic (SE) factors. METHODS: A cross-sectional survey was conducted including 1190 children aged 10-12 years and their parents, during school years 2014-2016. Primary schools from five Greek counties (including Athens metropolitan area) were randomly selected. Parental and child data were collected through self-administered, anonymous questionnaires. Children's weight status was based on gender- and age-specific tables derived from the International Obesity Task Force body mass index (BMI) cut offs. General Linear Model (GLM), Univariate and multivariate analyses were applied. Multiple logistic regressions was used to determine the association between children and parents' weight status. RESULTS: Childhood prevalence of overweight and obesity was 25.9\% (21.8\% overweight and 4.1\% obese), with prevalence being significantly higher in males (31.7\% compared to 21.3\%; P for gender differences {$<$} 0.001). The percent of overweight and obese male (34.4\% and 43.1\%) and female children (20.3\% and 31.8\%) significantly increased with paternal overweight and obesity status, respectively. The same relationship was observed between male children and maternal overweight and obesity status (43.4\% and 65.7\%). This was not evident among females (27\% and 23.2\%). Regression analysis showed a significant positive association with parental BMI, a negative association with both parental educational levels (low to high), living space, and parental age (P {\$<\$} 0.05, for all). Children's likelihood of being overweight or obese increased significantly with increasing parental weight status (P {\$<\$} 0.001). CONCLUSIONS: Parental weight status remained the most significant predictive factor for early adolescence obesity among various SE factors. Health promotion strategies should consider parental education as an effective childhood obesity preventive measure.},
  langid        = {english},
  pmcid         = {PMC6512222},
  pmid          = {31143794},
  keywords      = {Children weight status,health promotion,obesity risk factors,parental weight status,socioeconomic factors}
}
```

Comment: Might be duplicate of [verbatim - Produce a hyperlinked DOI? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50023/produce-a-hyperlinked-doi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `\detokenize` the argument in the second part of the definition of `\doi` to remove the TeX-special meanings of characters such as `_` ("underscore").

```
\renewcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

And, if you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document, do load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1` to ensure that the detokenized `_` character is printed correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}
@article{notaraParentalWeightStatus2019,
  title         = {Parental Weight Status and Early Adolescence Body Weight in Association with Socioeconomic Factors},
  author        = {Notara, Venetia and Magriplis, Emmanuella and Prapas, Christos and Antonogeorgos, George and Rojas-Gil, Andrea Paola and Kornilaki, Ekaterina N. and Lagiou, Areti and Panagiotakos, Demosthenes B.},
  year          = {2019},
  journal       = {Journal of Education and Health Promotion},
  volume        = {8},
  pages         = {77},
  issn          = {2277-9531},
  doi           = {10.4103/jehp.jehp_14_19},
  langid        = {english},
  pmcid         = {PMC6512222},
  pmid          = {31143794},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue, 
            bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]%
           {hyperref}
%\usepackage{doi} % <-- do you really need this package?
\providecommand{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\detokenize{#1}}}

\hyphenation{socio-econo-mic}

\begin{document}
\citet{notaraParentalWeightStatus2019}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks a bit senseless to first load the doi package (which goes into quite some troubles to handle such cases) and then to overwrite its command again.
If you only want to get rid of the text the package adds, redefine `\doitext`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}
\renewcommand{\doitext}{}

\begin{document}
    \cite{notaraParentalWeightStatus2019}
    \bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

[image]