# Automatically link bibliography entry to Google Scholar when no url field is present

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

Something I thought would be absolutely amazing but is way beyond my BibLaTeX skills: whenever there is no url field, generate a link that searches for the title, authors and year on Google Scholar. So for a paper named "Rocket Science", written by J. Doe in 1999 the link `http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Rocket+Science%22+author%3Adoe&as_ylo=1999&as_yhi=1999` would be generated and put on the paper name of the bibliography entry or where ever it would be convenient.

I think exact title, year and author should be almost always unambiguous and available. This is how the cryptic query above would look when entered:

[image: screen capture of the result of the search query]

So if somebody liked the idea *and* had the biblatex-fu to implement it, I'd be totally jazzed :)

Comment: Looks doable, but it would be handy to know the exact format you want the query in. For example, we could just dump say author, title, year and journal into the `q=` part, or do something more complex. Which fields do you want, and how 'sophisticated' are you after?

Comment: Part of the answer (inserting the hyperlink once you have generated the url) may build on this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography/64695#64695

Comment: This is really something the backend should do. It could be part of the biber sourcemapping feature and probably not that hard to implement.

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe that was not human-readable enough and too compressed. The link encodes author, year and title. These fields are almost always available (unlike journal or something) except for things like collections, where you only have editors. The search string encoded in the URL above is `"Rocket Science" author:doe` and you will get a line that says that you're searching in the timeframe 1999--1999.

Comment: I added a screen shot to illustrate.

Comment: @Christian OK, that's a slightly different requirement to the one I tried first :-) It may take a little while, but I'll see what I can do (I have a feeling I should be able to avoid using `expl3`).

Comment: Because of the consensus that biber would be the perfect place to implement this, I wrote a feature request for biber: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3563625&group_id=228270&atid=1073795

Comment: @JosephWright Great, thanks for trying this :) And sorry that I didn't express myself clearly enough in the first place :/

Comment: Nice idea, I can imagine this saving some time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a a solution which requires biblatex 2.3 and biber 1.3 (both in DEV on SF). Firstly, let's allow a new "AUTOURL" field in all entries so we can populate this as we probably don't want to use the URL field as it can be printed in the bibliography. We can change our driver to test for the AUTOURL field and to add a hyperlink on the title or whatever. Here I'm concentrating just on generating the url data for this.

Add this to your `biblatex-dm.cfg`

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{autourl}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=uri]{autourl}
```

Now we do the real work with the biber sourcemap feature which is better than hard-coding all this as we can then create arbitrary URLs:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
     \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldset=autourl, fieldvalue={http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="}]
      \step[fieldsource=title]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, fieldvalue={"+author:}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\A([^,]+)\s*,}]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, fieldvalue={$1}, append]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, fieldvalue={&as_ylo=}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, fieldvalue={&as_yhi=}, append]
      \step[fieldset=autourl, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}
```

Biber will also URL escape any UTF-8 or LaTeX char macros which end up in the URL due to splicing in parts of other fields so you don't have to worry about that.

This results in a field in the .bbl like this:

[image]

Which you can reference as the "AUTOURL" field in some logic such as the TITLE field format to add it as a hyperref link. To take a simple example:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\href{\thefield{autourl}}{#1}}
```

Here is a more sophisticated example that works for all entry types in their default configuration without changing it and uses the auto-generated URL only when no custom one is available:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\iffieldundef{url}{\href{\thefield{autourl}}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}{\href{\thefield{url}}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\iffieldundef{url}{\href{\thefield{autourl}}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}{\href{\thefield{url}}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]{title}{\iffieldundef{url}{\href{\thefield{autourl}}{#1}}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
```

Only the `url` field is used to replace `autourl`, not URLs generated from `doi` or `eprint`. A production version should also respect `\ifhyperref` and should be made more robust against missing fields.

Comment: Sounds great. What does "some logic" mean exactly? How would I make every `title` actually be something like `\href{AUTOURL}{ORIGINALTITLE}`?

Comment: I updated the example with an example field format for TITLE which uses the URL generated.

Comment: @PLK: What does `append` do? Is this a method to add information to an existing key. (e.g. keyworkds)?

Comment: It just appends the fieldvalue to the current value instead of replacing it. New in 1.3/2.3

Comment: @PLK: Great: This is a feature I missed.

Comment: Looks perfect! I am going to install the biber and biblatex development trees and will then give this a try.

Comment: I'm looking into making it a bit easier to extract parts of information from a field for later insertion into another field. I'll update the example if necessary.

Comment: I have changed the example slightly after improving the functionality of the biber code for this. Now you can grab parts of fields using the usual regexp parentheses and refer to these in later `fieldvalue` lines. So now you can directly pull out just the lastname of the author to put in the URL (assuming, in the example, a "Last, First" format). I have put this example in the biblatex 2.3 PDF doc as it's quite useful. I have updated the biber/biblatex dev versions with this.

Comment: The part in the .bbl gets generated correctly but somehow the `\DeclareFieldFormat` I put in the header is ignored as the title is no link in the generated PDF. There are no warnings or errors :/

Comment: You might need an explicit `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: No, forgetting that would have gotten me an error I guess. But I just realized that I have to be more precise: it seems to work for certain entry types but not for others. `online`, `techreport`, `book`, and `misc` work; `article`, `conference`, and `thesis` don't.

Comment: That's normal. If an entrytype has a type-specific format, it takes precedence and the ones you say don't work probably have that. For example, to make ARTICLEs work, do: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\href{\thefield{autourl}}{#1}}`

Comment: Great, thanks! Now everything seems to be working perfectly :) I added the three `\DeclareFieldFormat` commands I ended up using to your answer, based on the default configuration of biblatex.

Answer (score 17):

### Second version

Most of the work can be done using `biblatex` if we assume that the only tricky characters are spaces. To do the conversion, I've used a special name format which simply saves surnames to a temporary variable using `+` to separate them. The title is surrounded by `\%22` (encoded `"`"), and the first and last years are set to be the same value (there is no check on the validity of the year).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author = {Doe, J. and Other, Arthur N.},
  title  = {Rocket Science},
  year   = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_catcode_space:N \ %
\cs_new_protected:Npn\spacetoplus#1%
  {\tl_greplace_all:Nnn#1{ }{+}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{searchurl}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {}
    {\gappto{\bbx@gtempa}{+}}%
  \xdef\bbx@gtempa{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\bbx@gtempa}%
    author\@percentchar 3A%
    \unexpanded{#1}%
  }%
}

\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{url}
    {%
      \savefield{title}{\bbx@gtempa}%
      \xdef\bbx@gtempa{%
        http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=
        \@percentchar
        22%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\bbx@gtempa}%
      }
      \xdef\bbx@gtempa{%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\bbx@gtempa}%
        \@percentchar 22+%
      }
      \printnames[searchurl]{author}%
      \edef\bbx@tempa{&as_ylo=\thefield{year}&as_yhi=\thefield{year}}%
      \xdef\bbx@gtempa{%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\bbx@gtempa}%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\bbx@tempa}%
      }%
      \spacetoplus{\bbx@gtempa}%
      \restorefield{url}{\bbx@gtempa}%
    }
    {}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printurldate}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I've loaded `expl3` for a prebuild 'replace all' command, but this could be recoded without `expl3`. As that's not the key point here I've not bothered!

### First version

Most of the work required here is to get the data out of `biblatex`'s internal format and correctly escape into a URL string. That's particularly true for the author part, which is tricky as there are various braces to strip. I've decided to tackle this using the experimental LaTeX3 [`l3str`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3str) module (edit: in January 2013 encoding functions moved to `l3str-convert`), which includes code for the URL encoding, along with the general LaTeX3 programming support system to do all of the construction. (You have to do the encoding in bits so that `+` is left unencoded between fields you are passing.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author = {Doe, J. and Other, Arthur N.},
  title  = {Rocket Science},
  year   = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,l3str-convert}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \__searchurl_search_str
\str_new:N \__searchurl_tmp_str
\tl_new:N \__searchurl_tmp_tl
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \createsearchurl
  {
    \str_set:Nn \__searchurl_search_str
      { http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q= }
    \savefield* { year } { \__searchurl_tmp_tl }
    \cs_if_exist:NT \__searchurl_tmp_tl
      { \str_put_right:NV \__searchurl_search_str \__searchurl_tmp_tl }
    \clist_map_function:nN { title , journal } \__searchurl_add_field:n
    \savename* { author } { \__searchurl_tmp_tl }
    \cs_if_exist:NT \__searchurl_tmp_tl
      { \__searchurl_convert_authors: }
    \restorefield { url } { \__searchurl_search_str }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__searchurl_add_field:n #1
  {
    \savefield* {#1} { \__searchurl_tmp_tl }
    \cs_if_exist:NT \__searchurl_tmp_tl
      {
        \str_set_convert:NVnn \__searchurl_tmp_str
          \__searchurl_tmp_tl { } { latin1 / url }  
        \str_put_left:Nn \__searchurl_tmp_str { + }
        \str_put_right:NV \__searchurl_search_str \__searchurl_tmp_str   
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__searchurl_convert_authors:
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__searchurl_convert_authors:nn
      \__searchurl_tmp_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__searchurl_convert_authors:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#2} 
      { \__searchurl_convert_authors:nnnnnnnnn ##1 }
  }
\group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_active:N \~
  \char_set_catcode_space:N \ %
  \cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\__searchurl_convert_authors:nnnnnnnnn%
    #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9%
    {%
      \tl_set:Nn\__searchurl_tmp_tl{#2}%
      \tl_replace_all:Nnn\__searchurl_tmp_tl{~}{ }% 
      \str_set_convert:NVnn\__searchurl_tmp_str
        \__searchurl_tmp_tl{}{latin1/url}%
      \str_put_left:Nn\__searchurl_tmp_str{+}%
      \str_put_right:NV\__searchurl_search_str\__searchurl_tmp_str
    }%
\group_end:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set_convert:Nnnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_put_right:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{url}
    {\createsearchurl}
    {}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printurldate}}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I've build the search to use author surnames only, with any non-breaking spaces converted to normal ones before encoding.

As PLK notes, this could probably be done rather more easily using biber at an earlier stage!

Comment: Will this strip out control sequences like the ones you find in names with accented charaters?

Comment: @Audrey I've told the `l3str` module to use latin1 encoding for the output, so it will escape accented characters, but not control sequence versions (_e.g._ `é` is fine, `\'{e}` will give odd results).

Comment: OK. I suspect a comparable solution could be obtained without l3 using `\thefield` and friends. We can access unformatted name list elements with an indexing directive. For example: `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{getname}{\gdef\thelastname{#1}}` and `\indexnames[getname][-1]{author}`.

Comment: @Audrey Yes, quite true. I mainly went for `expl3` here as I know that there is a URL-encoding function available. I suspect Heiko Oberdiek has one too, for `hyperref`, _etc._, but don't know the interface and wanted to get some ideas down. It's not clear from the question exactly how to handle names, so I went for a simple loop to be going on with.

Comment: Ah, OK. Is there anything wrong with just using the percent encoding: `\def\scholarurl{http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=\%22\strfield{title}\%22}` and `\restorefield{url}{\scholarurl}`?

Comment: @Audrey My understanding is that valid URLs should not contain spaces at all (they should always be encoded). Of course, it may well work (certainly does here with a few quick tests), but I was aiming for reasonably 'robust'. Why not post a solution working this way and the OP can then try both out :-)

Comment: Spaces are replaced by `+`.

Comment: Wow, this code looks like it took a while. Thank you :) Unfortunately I get a "LaTeX error: "str/unknown-enc" Encoding scheme 'latin1' (filtered: 'latin1') unknown.' Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Christian Probably a version issue with `l3str`. However, the update avoids all of that, so is probably a lot less risky!

Comment: Sorry for the haiku; I added a missing ampersand. The new code works great already and I'm totally amazed. It doesn't handle the two authors well though. The second should have an `author:` in front of it, too, yielding the string `author%3Adoe+author%3Aother`. I'll try myself if I can get the url to '\href' the title instead of creating a new url field. This will enhance my understanding of the code I guess.

Comment: I forgot to explain the haiku thing: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters-wtf

Comment: Wow, this is weirder and harder to tinker with than I thought. Maybe I can do some more tinkering this afternoon. But feel free to just implement it if for you it's a piece of cake ;)

Comment: @Christian I've adjusted the code to handle each author separately, and to escape the `:` as requested.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about the bounty once I activated it. There should be a reminder when you can actually use it ... I don't understand the time limit anyway for bounties that are marked as being for existing answers. Anyway, here you go :)