# set DOI link on Journal Name with bibtex/.bst

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get DOI links in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography)

I'm struggling with a bibliography style problem. I would like to have the doi link set on the journal name, and then hide the doi key from the bibliography list.

I've tried to write some bst-bibtex function, which produces many errors, warning me that the stack was empty. I can't remember all the errors. If you know something about `bibtex` code, help me please.

```
FUNCTION {journal_doi}
{ doi duplicate$ empty$
  { }
  { "\href{http://doi.org/" doi * "}" *
    journal empty$
      { }
      { "{" * journal * "}" * }
    if$ 
  if$
  }
}
```

Comment: You can adapt the answer given [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/16873). Which bibliography style are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Building on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/16873), I would define a new function in the `.bst` file:

```
FUNCTION {doilink}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ doi empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
if$
}
```

Then you need to find how the journal information is printed in your `.bst` file (this depends on which particular `.bst` you are using). Just add a call to `doilink` before outputting the journal information. If you also want to remove the doi from the output, you also need to find the place in the `.bst` where this is printed and delete those lines. It is difficult to be more specific without knowing more about your particular bibliography configuration.

Note that a very good guide to BibTeX may be found [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast) (or `texdoc tamethebeast` in a shell). There would also be `biblatex` solutions.

**EDIT**: Here is an example based on the `plain.bst` style file:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize doilink "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

I have just added the call to the `doilink` function at the proper place (and you also need to add `doi` in the `ENTRY {...}` fields description at the beginning of the `.bst` file.