# How to change "\url" to "\href" in the .bst file

Tags: bibtex

I'm using LaTeX with BibTeX to write my paper. The .bst file is written by someone else.

In the .bst file, he wrote a function to deal with the \url as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.url} { 
  "\url{" swap$ * "}" * 
}
```

Now I want to change "`\url`" to "`\href`". For example,

`\url{http://www.aaa.com}`  -->   `\href{http://www.aaa.com}{http://www.aaa.com}`

The minimum working example can be downloaded from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jinglou/p2017-hcn-co-sod/master/Question.zip)

Thank you.

Comment: You can edit and create a modified `.bst` file (making the correction), or you could, in your document, reassign `\url` to behave as `\href`, assuming the argument lists were compatible.  However, it would help if you edit your question to provide a minimum working example to show the actual problem.

Comment: The `hyperref` package provides the `\href` macro... **and** the `\url` macro...

Comment: Thank you for your help. The minimum working example can be downloaded from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jinglou/p2017-hcn-co-sod/master/Question.zip

Comment: Why exactly? As others mention, when hyperref is loaded, that **is** how `\url`  work.

Answer (score 1):

I referenced this question [set DOI link on Journal Name with bibtex/.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76174/set-doi-link-on-journal-name-with-bibtex-bst) and have solved this problem.

The code is

```
FUNCTION {format.url} {    
  "\href{" url * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * 
}
```