# ArXiv link over the arXiv-id, e.g. over [2012.xxxxx], with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, arxiv, doi, custom-bib

With the following code

```
\documentclass[a6paper,2pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=27mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[style=verbose, isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{hol.bib}

% citation --> footnote
\renewcommand{\cite}{\footcite}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}


\begin{document}

...famous\cite{Maldacena:1997re}...

\begin{filecontents}{hol.bib}
@article{Maldacena:1997re,
    author = "Maldacena, Juan Martin",
    title = "{The Large N limit of superconformal field theories and supergravity}",
    eprint = "hep-th/9711200",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    reportNumber = "HUTP-97-A097, HUTP-98-A097",
    doi = "10.1023/A:1026654312961",
    journal = "Adv. Theor. Math. Phys.",
    volume = "2",
    pages = "231--252",
    year = "1998"
}

\end{filecontents}
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` produces:

[image]

The problem is that it is too verbose (I know I can strip
the bibliography changing the style as I've started to do with ISBN, but I'm after other feature). I have seen [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76174/set-doi-link-on-journal-name-with-bibtex-bst?noredirect=1&lq=1) but that solution is based on changing a `.bst` file (which I've just learnt from moeve's comment, is not even used by `biblatex`).

What I wish is

1. to keep footnote-citation, but
2. to remove the **word** arXiv (since we all know it's arXiv by seeing the number) and just show the id, [hep-th/9711200] in this case.

So, I have a MWE, but no progress, since I don't even know the name of the bibmacro I have to modify.

Comment: `biblatex` does not use `.bst` files to format the citation or bibliography output. It uses `.bbx` and `.cbx` files.

Comment: For your actual question, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format of the `arxiv` `eprint` as follows

```
\documentclass[a6paper,2pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=27mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[style=verbose, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{%
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{https://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
         \nolinkurl{#1}%
         \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
           {}
           {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
      {\nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Maldacena:1997re,
    author = "Maldacena, Juan Martin",
    title = "{The Large N limit of superconformal field theories and supergravity}",
    eprint = "hep-th/9711200",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    reportNumber = "HUTP-97-A097, HUTP-98-A097",
    doi = "10.1023/A:1026654312961",
    journal = "Adv. Theor. Math. Phys.",
    volume = "2",
    pages = "231--252",
    year = "1998"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
...famous\autocite{Maldacena:1997re}...
\end{document}
```

[image: Juan Martin Maldacena. “The Large N limit of superconformal field theories and supergravity”. In: Adv. Theor. Math. Phys. 2 (1998), pp. 231–252. doi: 10.1023/A:1026654312961. [hep-th/9711200].]