# Make the bibliography entry link to online resource without showing the href/address

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, natbib, links

So i have my bibliography, and it looks exactly as i want, there's no problem with that. I *don't* want the entries in the bibliography show the url (unless it's specifically an online resource), and i have achieved this using the custom bib thing. That's all good.

[image]

What i would like though, is for the actual entries to be links to their online resources. I have DOIs and links to all my references, so that's not an issue, I'd just like to know how to get them to all be used in the bibliography to make the entries links. I've looked at lots of other questions on here, and can't find any that do what i'd like.

all my bibtex entries are of this form:

```
@ARTICLE{Ziolkowski2012,
  author = {{Zi\'{o}\l{l}kowski}, M and {Vikár}, A and Mayes, ML and Bencsura,
    A and Lendvay, G et al.},
  title = {Modeling the electron-impact dissociation of methane},
  journal = {Journal of Chemical Physics},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {137},
  pages = {22A510},
  abstract = {Blah Blah Blah},
  doi = {10.1063/1.4733706},
  file = {Modeling the electron-impact dissociation of methane.pdf:Modeling the electron-impact dissociation of methane.pdf:PDF},
  owner = {will},
  timestamp = {2013.02.11},
  url = {dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4733706}
}
```

I am using `hyperref` and `natbib`, which i would except to be able to do this, but i can't see how.

Comment: What about [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/31323) answer?

Comment: @Hackbard_C that looks perfect, I'll try it tomorrow. I currently generate my .bst file from a .dbj file, so i'll have to manually edit this in each time i change it, but it's basically finished now, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Hackbard_C okay, so that works. The porblem i have now, is that i'd like the journal name *and* the vol(number) to be the link, rather than just the vol(number). I'd follow in the instructions in that answer, but i don't have a `FUNCTION { format.journal...` in my bst file, and i don't know how to write my own without breaking it all!

Comment: @Hackbard_C Okay, nevermind, i worked it out. Works great. thanks.

Comment: Use `FUNCTION {article}` and add the `doilink` function like this `journal emphasize doilink "journal" output.check`

Comment: Can't tick a comment as an answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn my comment(s) into an answer:

As mentioned [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/31323) answer provides the basic idea to solve your problem.

If you also want to be journal clickable, use `FUNCTION {article}` and add the new defined `doilink` function in the corresponding line:

```
journal emphasize doilink "journal" output.check
```