# How to write the clickable DOI in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, doi

Instead of adding a hyperlink DOI to each of the bibliography items, I do not want  to write the DOI explicitly but to make another field of the bibliographic item clickable with an hyperlink to the website. In some journals, the hyperlink is associated to the group "Journal Name, volume, page number" for instance. the pic shows below:
[image]

=====================================

how can I custom my .bst file to make it.
here is the bst file
[gbt-7714-2015-numerical.bst](https://github.com/qiuzhu/BITthesis/blob/master/gbt-7714-2015-numerical.bst)

Comment: You can follow the instructions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/117534

Comment: Any news here? Does the comment above help?