# Why does hyperref break natbib?

Tags: hyperref, natbib, doi

I want to use [`hyperref`](http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) with [`natbib`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/natbib/natbib.pdf) for the elsarticle class, including correct DOIs but I get strange errors or output no matter what I try:

(All attempts compiled with `bibtex` and `pdflatex`)

**Attempt 0: Success, without hyperref**

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
  @article{Ashburner2005,
    author = {Ashburner, John and Friston, Karl J},
    doi = {10.1016/j.neuroimage.2005.02.018},
    journal = {NeuroImage},
    title = {{Unified segmentation.}},
    year = {2005}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
  \cite{Ashburner2005}
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
  \bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Attempt 1: Death by hyperref**

```
\usepackage{hyperref}                 % <-- added this to preamble
```

Output:

ERROR:
`Undefined control sequence. \doi{\bibinfo{doi}{10.1016/j.neuroimage.2005.02.018}}.`

[image]

**Attempt 2: uri package**

```
\usepackage[doipre={DOI:~}]{uri}      % <-- added this to preamble
```

Output:

No errors, but DOI is wrong.

[image]

**Attempt 3-A: user-defined `\doi` command:**

As suggested in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography/3803#3803), I tried:

```
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/{#1}}{doi: {#1}}}
```

Output:

ERROR:
`Undefined control sequence. \doi{\bibinfo{doi}{10.1016/j.neuroimage.2005.02.018}}.`

*Compile failed*

**Attempt 3-B: user-defined `\doi` command, updated:**

```
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\detokenize{#1}}{doi: \detokenize{#1}}}
```

Output:

No errors, but DOI is wrong again, in a different way.

[image]

In every case where the DOI link is wrong, the link also breaks.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, making `\bibinfo` work by expansion.

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
  @article{Ashburner2005,
    author = {Ashburner, John and Friston, Karl J},
    doi = {10.1016/j.neuroimage.2005.02.018},
    journal = {NeuroImage},
    title = {{Unified segmentation.}},
    year = {2005}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{DOI \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\texttt{#1}}}
\makeatletter
% expandable version of ...
\def\bibinfo#1{%
  \@ifundefined{bibinfo@X@#1}%
    {\@firstofone}
    {\csname bibinfo@X@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \cite{Ashburner2005}
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
  \bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```