# Adding Publication in moderncv template

Tags: bibtex, moderncv

How can I add the following publication (for example) in the `moderncv` template?

> Albert Einstein. Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K ̈orper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]. Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921,1905.

I have created a file called `publication.bib` where I stored the information:

```
 @article{einstein,
         author = "Albert Einstein",
         title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
         journal = "Annalen der Physik",
         volume = "322",
         number = "10",
         pages =  "891--921",
         year = "1905",
         DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
   }
```

Then I have called the `publication.bib` in `document.tex`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}       

 \moderncvcolor{green}   

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       

  \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

  \name{John}{Doe}
  \title{Resumé title}            

  \address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}

  \phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}         

  \phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}        

  \phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}      

  \email{john@doe.org}         

  \homepage{www.johndoe.com}       

  \extrainfo{additional information}     

   \begin{document}

   \makecvtitle

   \section{Education}
   \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
  \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}


 \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
 \bibliography{publication}

 \end{document}
```

The `document.tex` run normally. But it doesn't show the information contained in `publication.bib`.

[image]

Why doesn't it showing the reference?

Comment: you need to create a file called publications.bib, and input your information there using BibTex. check this out: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Bibliography_management_with_Bibtex

Comment: @EladDen I have created publication.bib. The `document.tex` run normally. But it doesn't show the information contained in `publication.bib`.  I have edited my post.

Comment: You need to `\cite` or `\nocite` the works you want to appear in the bibliography list (either explicitly `\cite{einstein}` which creates a label or `\nocite{einstein}` which does not, or in general with `\nocite{*}`). And you need to run BibTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly did it.

The only thing missing is that you need to use command `\nocite{*}` to tell BibTeX that all bib entrys should be added to the bibliography.

Please see the following MWE (I used `filecontents` to have bib file and tex code together in one MWE; important changing is marked with `<========`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author  = "Albert Einstein",
  title   = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
              [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal = "Annalen der Physik",
  volume  = "322",
  number  = "10",
  pages   =  "891--921",
  year    = "1905",
  DOI     = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}       

\moderncvcolor{green}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}            
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}         
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}        
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}      
\email{john@doe.org}         
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}       
\extrainfo{additional information}     


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\nocite{*} % <==========================================================
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname} % To use bib file created by filecontents

\end{document}
```

with the resulting page after compiling with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Why doesn't the DOI come in the reference?

Comment: In my publication, there are 9 authors and when I was running the tex file , it was showing the error `Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding utf8.`  This error massage has gone by  deleting `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} `.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography for DOI