# DOI is not shown in the bibliography by natbib

Tags: natbib, doi

I'm writing a document in LaTeX (in Visual Studio Code using `LaTeX Workshop` extension) and using `natbib` for bibliography. The problem is in the bibliography it doesn't show the DOI, even for `\bibliographystyle{apa}`.

I have tried loading `doi` and `url` before and after `natbib` and I have tried to make the output by both `pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex*2` and `latexmk`.

This is how the entry in the `.bib` file:

```
   @article{Drury2005,
abstract = {blah blah blah.},
author = {Drury, John and Cocking, Christopher and Beale, Joseph and Hanson, Charlotte and Rapley, Faye},
doi = {10.1348/014466604X18523},
isbn = {2044-8309},
issn = {01446665},
journal = {British Journal of Social Psychology},
number = {3},
pages = {309--328},
pmid = {16238842},
title = {{The phenomenology of empowerment in collective action}},
volume = {44},
year = {2005}
}
```

Any ideas how to handle this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`apa.bst`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/apa.bst) dates back to 1992 a few years before the DOI system was introduced. You need to use a style that can handle DOIs.

Comment: The styles of the [`urlbst`](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst) bundle know the `DOI`. So do several other more modern `.bst` styles such as [`apacite`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) (should be used with the `apacite` package and tries to implement full APA style), [`din1505`](https://ctan.org/pkg/din1505)'s styles also know DOIs. `.bst` files produced by [`cursom-bib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) can also support DOIs.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, the `apacite` works well. I needed the DOI to become a hyperlink but I could do it by defining this command `\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}` before `\begin{document}` (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3805/166234)). The only problem remaining is the space **after the colon** and before the DOI string (as in "doi: 10.1348/014466604X18523") which shouldn't be there according to the APA style. Playing with `.bst` file didn't seem to be easy. Any idea how to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lyx, you need the "Natbibapa" module – you can enable it in the document settings. After I enabled the module every problem I previously had with bibliographies disappeard!

N.B. I think you should use the "apacite" style for bibliography if you follow my advice.