# APA 7th ed. for elsarticle bibliography

Tags: elsarticle, bibliographystyle, apa7

I am using the following environment

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.2)

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Here are examples of the generated citations in attached image:
[image]

However, a reviewer has commented that ***the referencing style needs to be revised according to APA style (7th ed.): for 3 or more authors use et al. even on first mention in the main text.***

So far I have tried to switch to biblatex but the \printbibliography does not produce any output.
On the other hand, \bibliographystyle{apa} makes the citation look like

> [year] author...

Can you please suggest an easy solution for  APA 7 citations on elsarticle document?

N.B. I can not understand the difference between bibtex and biblatex.

Comment: For the difference between BibTeX and `biblatex` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. As far as I know there is no BIbTeX implementation of 7th edition APA style available at the moment. But `biblatex` is unlikely to work on a journal submission (either because the template does not support it, or because it does not work well with the journal's publishing workflow). It's probably best to contact the editor about this. Sometimes journals apply the desired style during their publishing process and are not too fussed about the style you use as long as it's consistent and complete.

Comment: Hi @moewe! I was just reading one of your comment in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439911/doi-is-not-shown-in-the-bibliography-by-natbib

My update- 
Using : \bibliographystyle{apa}\biboptions{authoryear,sort,comma}   , I could generate a probable APA format. However, the DOI is not produced as URL. If I use apacite as you mentioned there, will it be a solution?

Comment: using apacite i get this error: Undefined control sequence. \st@rtbibchapter

Comment: That comment is from 2018 when the current version of APA style was the 6th edition. `apacite` currently only provides 6th edition APA style. It does not give you the desired 7th edition style. `\bibliographystyle{apa}` is probably even worse since it is much older (plus, I don't know if it ever fully implemented APA guidelines). Additionally, `apacite` is quite a complex beast that may not be compatible with your journal template. I really think your best bet is to get in touch with the editor/journal staff and ask them to proceed, chances are they might tell you to ignore the review comment