# Removing the space between after "doi: " in APA bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, doi, apacite

I'm using `apacite` to produce the bibliography. I'm also using this line of code `\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}` before `\begin{document}` to hyperlink the DOI string which works perfectly. It was taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3805/166234) and I had to change it a little bit since the `apacite` prints out "doi: "

The problem is, in the bibliography there is a white space between the colon and the string which shouldn't be there according to APA style.

As an example I get `doi: 10.1348/014466604X18523` in the bibliography which should be `doi:10.1348/014466604X18523`.

I tried to play with `apacite.bst` but I couldn't figure it out. How can I fix this, preferably in the main `.tex` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is there in the `.bbl` file already

```
\begin{APACrefDOI} \doi{10.1348/014466604X18523} \end{APACrefDOI}
```

So you could edit the `.bst` file not to add a space, or we can add `\ignorespaces` to the `APACrefDOI` environment.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}% load apacite after hyperref, see §8.2 of the apacite manual

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  doi     = {10.1348/014466604X18523},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{APACrefDOI}{%
  \global\let\old@doi\doi
  \if@doi
    \doiprefix
  \else
    \global\let\doi\@gobble
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
  }{\global\let\doi\old@doi }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you prefer to modify the `.bst` file, you need to follow the steps below.

1. Locate `apacite.bst` on your machine for example by typing `kpsewhich apacite.bst`.
2. Copy the file to a place where LaTeX can find it (https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf), the directory of your document will do just fine, and **rename** it to `apacite-nspdoi.bst`, say. Note that the license of `apacite.bst` requires you to change the name of the file if you modify it.
3. Open `apacite-nspdoi.bst` and insert a header with the new file name and the current date
4. Find `FUNCTION {begin.end.doi.env}` and replace the entire function with

   ```
   FUNCTION {begin.end.doi.env}
   { "\begin{APACrefDOI}"% removed trailing space here
     " \end{APACrefDOI} "
   }
   ```

   Where the only change to the original is that you delete the last space in `"\begin{APACrefDOI} "` to make it `"\begin{APACrefDOI}"`.
5. Save the file and use `\bibliography{apacite-nspdoi}` in your document.

Alternatively you can get `apacite-nspdoi.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/520dbd08e1a7a3129a8838d5e6be34a3

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}% load apacite after hyperref, see §8.2 of the apacite manual

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  doi     = {10.1348/014466604X18523},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{apacite-nspdoi}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The output is as above.

Answer (score 1):

APA style guide re. DOI's is [here](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2017/03/doi-display-guidelines-update-march-2017.html). If you want to use the style where you have "https://doi.org/XXXXXX" **and** you want it to be a clickable link from your .pdf than you can add the following to your preamble.

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{https://doi.org/#1}}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}
\makeatother
```