# Bibliography for IoP Journals

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, links, doi

I am using a bib file for a single column article to be submitted to IoP.

At the end of my tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
```

I have

```
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{bib_file}
```

However, I cannot show the items as in

[image]

Instead, it is everything black. How can I be sure that the references will show the doi link (light blue)?

Also, the references appear separated by commas: [12,13,14,15] instead of showing [12-15].

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code example of what you have so far? The `cite` package could be an option to get cite ranges [12-15].

Comment: It works for the range of papers! Any ideas about the doi links?

Comment: Looking at http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/iopart-num/iopart-num.bst I don't see that the style uses the `doi` field at all.

Comment: No, it has to be added. I try something similar to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography/76116#76116 but still it doesn't work completely.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the `.bst` file to add the DOI links as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/109339).

1. Download [`iopart-num.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/iopart-num/iopart-num.bst) and rename it `iopart-num-mod.bst`.
2. Add the following function to `iopart-num-mod.bst`:

   ```
   FUNCTION {doilink}
   { duplicate$ empty$
   { pop$ "" }
   { doi empty$
       { skip$ }
       { "\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }
   if$
   }
   ```
3. Call the function right after the part you wish to be the hyperlink. E.g. in the `article` function right after `format.vol.num.pages`:

   ```
   ...
   format.vol.num.pages doilink output
   ...
   ```

   This will create a hyperlink from the volume and pages.
4. Add `doi` field in `ENTRY`.

Here's an MWE the modified bibliography style in combination with the `cite` and `hyperref` packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib_file.bib}
@article{Rueda_2014,
    author  = {Rueda, A and others},
    title   = {Title},
    journal = {Optica},
    volume  = {3},
    pages   = {597},
    year    = {2014},
    doi     = {123456/798}
}
@article{Rueda_2015,
    author  = {Rueda, A and others},
    title   = {Title},
    journal = {Optica},
    volume  = {3},
    pages   = {597},
    year    = {2015},
    doi     = {123456/798}
}
@article{Rueda_2016,
    author  = {Rueda, A and others},
    title   = {Title},
    journal = {Optica},
    volume  = {3},
    pages   = {597},
    year    = {2016},
    doi     = {123456/798}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor = blue, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num-mod}
\begin{document}
\cite{Rueda_2014, Rueda_2015, Rueda_2016}
\bibliography{bib_file}
\end{document}
```

[image: refs]