# BibTeX code to create hyperlinks from either DOI or URL

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls, doi

Currently, I use below code (from [StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/45154)) to 'linkify' parts of BibTeX entries:

```
FUNCTION {doilink}
{ duplicate$ empty$
  { pop$ "" }
  { doi empty$
      { skip$ }
      { "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
  }
  if$
}
```

Appending this command to, e.g., the code for `format.title` formats the title as a hyperlink:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
  doilink
}
```

Question: How can I change the `doilink` code to use the `url` field when there is no `doi` field, and to do nothing if both are not present?

The solution should work with BibTeX (in particular, it should not require `biblatex`).