# Macro for writing DOI with optional link text

Tags: urls, doi

The `doi` package has a neat `\doi` command, that transforms a doi string into `\href{http://dx.doi.org/<the doi>}{doi:<the doi>}`. The `uri` package has something similar with the help of the `url` package.

I would like to have an extended version of that command that takes an arbitrary link text as an optional argument, like `\mydoi[Paper title]{doi}`. I tried that myself with the help of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308/21591), but the [weird characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3039/21591) in DOIs destroy that.

Take, e.g., the DOI `10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H`. I checked manually that
`\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H}{doi:10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4\textless263::AID-NET4\textgreater3.0.CO;2-H}` works, I just want a macro that produces that sequence from, say `\mydoi{10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H}`, or `\mydoi[Title]{10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H}`.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://shortdoi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0037%28199712%2930:4%3C263::AID-NET4%3E3.0.CO;2-H

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fluently, no need to escape any chars. Our macro `\xx@doi` is only a modification of original `\@doi` to treat the optional argument. In `\x@doi` we store the original `\@doi` so that we can redefine `\@doi`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}

\makeatletter
\let\x@doi\@doi
\def\@doi{\@ifnextchar[\xx@doi\x@doi}
\def\xx@doi[#1]#2{%
  \let\#\relax \let\_\relax \let\textless\relax \let\textgreater\relax
  \edef\x{\toks0={{#1}}}\x
  \edef\#{\@percentchar 23}\edef\_{_}%
    \edef\textless{\@percentchar 3C}\edef\textgreater{\@percentchar 3E}%
  \edef\x{\toks1={\noexpand\href{http://dx.doi.org/#2}}}\x
  \edef\x{\endgroup\doitext\the\toks1 \the\toks0}\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\doi{1000.00/01/23/45_153#111<abc>xyz}

\doi[My]{1000.00/01/23/45_153#111<abc>xyz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually a space is needed between `\the\toks1` and `\the\toks0` (as in doi.sty). Also, note that the odd-numbered token registers 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 are for global assignments only, while the even-numbered token registers 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 are for local assignments only (thanks to Heiko).

Comment: @AhmedMusa Thanks for the space. Considering the second issue, you should address the `doi` package maintainer, I only copy-paste-modified his code :)

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try this one using the `ifthen` package, that defines the first argument to be optional (indeed its set to `\empty` as default and the command displays one or the other version depenting on that default value

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref,ifthen}
\newcommand{\mydoi}[2][\empty]{%
    \ifx\empty#1%
        \href{http://dx.doi.org/#2}{doi: #2}%
    \else%
        \href{http://dx.doi.org/#2}{#1}%
    \fi%
}%
\begin{document}
Version 1: DOI \mydoi{DOI1}\\
Version 2: Link Text \mydoi[LinkText]{DOI2}
\end{document}
```

Which produces something like

[image: DOI Example]

(where of course both links link to the corresponding DOI which is nonsense in this example)

I also tested that with some DOIs I had available, though I'm not shure, what your “weird characters” are. For `.` `/` and such this works.

**Update 1**
The OP requested, that also the DOI `10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H` should work and noted, that escapting just the second argument of `\href` works. Encapsulating the second argument in a code environment escapes the noted characters, so one way would be to use the `listings` package as in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref,url,ifthen,listings}

\newcommand{\mydoi}[2][\empty]{%
    \ifx\empty#1%
        \href{http://dx.doi.org/#2}{doi: \lstinline!#2!}%
    \else%
        \href{http://dx.doi.org/#2}{#1}%
    \fi%
}%
\begin{document}
\mydoi{10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles fine. Though - at least on my system (MacTeX 2012) clicking on the link does not open the link in a browser.

Comment: This breaks, e.g., for `10.1007/978-3-540-39658-1_67`.

Comment: Because than you would have to escape the `_` to `\_`, that's why i asked :) I'll think about that and extend my answer, if i found something.

Comment: You can (and should) just escape that yourself, i.e. using `\mydoi{10.1007/978-3-540-39658-1\_67}` or `\mydoi[Flow Approximation]{10.1007/978-3-540-39658-1\_67}` works fine, i.e. the document compiled and the link works. The same of course for other sepcial characters as `&` and stuff in URLs.

Comment: This does not help much. For one, I don't want to escape all DOIs by hand (I have a lot), but even if I would, there is stuff like `\mydoi{10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4<263::AID-NET4>3.0.CO;2-H}`, which does not get better with `\mydoi{10.1002/(SICI)1097-0037(199712)30:4\textless263::AID-NET4\textgreater3.0.CO;2-H}`.

Comment: Uff, I haven't found a way up to now to escape the input for href, such that would work. I'm also working with a lot of DOIs; my Library (Papers2/Mac) escapes the DOIs when exporting them to the `.bib` file. Maybe extend your starting post with that information. If I'm getting an idea how to escape that, i.e. taking your DOIs as `#2` and escape them befor output into `\href` i'll give you a note.

Comment: I extended my answer, which I noticed yesterday and which should work the same as you noted in the original post. Though on my computer, the link is not clickable

Comment: @Ronny I recommend you to look up the definitions of `\doi` and `\@doi` in the file `doi.sty` to see how you have to define a macro that reads `#_<>` as strings and not as TeX special characters.

Comment: @Ronny And notice that you do not use `{ifthen}`, since `\ifx` is a TeX primitive: http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#ifx-rp

Comment: Ups, well i copied that from a bigger project and in striping down the commands ... well sometimes - thanks for the hint :)