# Hyperlink each reference entry to its corresponding DOI with natbib

Tags: natbib, doi, achemso, href

I am writting my Bachelor Thesis using Overleaf and I want to hyperlink each references to its corresponding DOI. I am using natibib package with the following commands.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}

.
.
.

\newpage
\bibliography{2_references.bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

I've tried many things such as adding `title = {\href{https://doi.org/10.1515/ntrev-2015-0031}{Improving the tribological behavior of internal combustion engines via the addition of nanoparticles to engine oils}}` at the .bib file. It does work and it links me to the corresponding DOI. I've tried also repeating this for all the required fields. However, when I place, for example: `author = {\href{https://doi.org/10.1515/ntrev-2015-0031}{Ali, Mohamed Kamal Ahmed and Xianjun, Hou}},` it is not displayed correctly in the pdf.

Is there a way that can automatically link all the reference entry to the DOI as it can be seen in many papers? Thank you.

[image]

This is how it looks using the `title = {\href{https://doi.org/10.1515/ntrev-2015-0031}{Improving the tribological behavior of internal combustion engines via the addition of nanoparticles to engine oils}}` command. It works perfectly and links me to the DOI.

[image]

This is how it looks using `\href{}{}` in each entry.

[image]

This is what I'm looking for. If you click any section of the reference it'll guide you to it's DOI.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: it should be `\bibliography{2_references}`, not `\bibliography{2_references.bib}`.

Comment: A general question: Why isn't it good enough to create a hyperlink between an entry's `title` field and some online depository of the publication? Put differently, what are you trying to achieve by mimicking the appearance of bibliographic entries that's practiced by some journals?

Comment: Thanks I'll change to \bibliography{2_references}. It is good enough, the thing is I'll be managing above 50 references, therefore I was looking for an automatized solution, and I don't want to add manually each DOI, but to read it directly from the ```doi = {}``` or ```url = {}``` field.

Comment: with biblatex/biber this sort of linking is rather easily implemented. With natbib and some older bibliography style this is often either rather hard or not possible.

Comment: @AlfonsoDiegoGarzaIsla - If each entry has a `doi` or `url` field, all you need to do, really, is load the `hyperref` package with suitably chosen options. You should be confident in your readers' ability to click on a doi field; nobody's going to complain to you that they weren't able to obtain a copy of some reference online because your publication failed to make the entire entry into a hyperlink.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3802/164050 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3039/164050 may provide some good answers to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but I needed to change to biblatex

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,bibstyle=chem-acs,articletitle=true,biblabel=brackets,doi=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{2_references}
\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
\iffieldundef{url}{%
\iffieldundef{doi}{#1}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}
{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}


\DeclareNameWrapperFormat[article,thesis,incollection]{author}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis,incollection]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis,incollection]{volume}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\textit{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis,incollection]{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\textit{ #1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis,incollection]{date}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\textbf{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis,incollection]{pages}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{#1}}
```

Comment: @Mario correctly commented that in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3802/164050 they provide good answers. And indeed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3803/192743 helps. In my case I just needed to do `\uspackage{doi}`.